# How can I match ALL terms using Regular Expressions in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I figured out how to check an OR case, `preg_match( "/(word1|word2|word3)/i", $string );`. What I can't figure out is how to match an AND case. I want to check that the string contains ALL the terms (case-insensitive).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible to do an AND match in a single regex using lookahead, eg.:

```
preg_match('/^(?=.*word1)(?=.*word2)(?=.*word3)/i', $string)
```

however, it's probably clearer and maybe faster to just do it outside regex:

```
preg_match('/word1/i', $string) && preg_match('/word2/i', $string) && preg_match('/word3/i', $string)
```

or, if your target strings are as simple as `word1`:

```
stripos($string, 'word1')!==FALSE && stripos($string, 'word2')!==FALSE && stripos($string, 'word3')!==FALSE
```

Comment: +1 for multiple regex. People somehow always forget that their source code can contain multiple lines when they think about regex. It's like a world where all software are Perl one-liners.

Comment: definitely multiple matches, splitting the problem is often the best way to turn a complex regexp into a trivial solution

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking about a situation in your question that may cause some problem using **and** case:

this is the situation

```
words = "abcd","cdef","efgh"
```

does  have to match in the string:

```
string = "abcdefgh"
```

maybe you should not using REG.EXP

Answer (score 0):

If you know the order that the terms will appear in, you could use something like the following:

```
preg_match("/(word1).*(word2).*(word3)/i", $string);
```

If the order of terms isn't defined, you will probably be best using 3 separate expressions and checking that they all matched. A single expression is possible but likely complicated.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match( "/word1.*word2.*word3)/i");
```

This works but they must appear in the stated order, you could of course alternate    `preg_match("/(word1.*word2.*word3|word1.*word3.*word2|word2.*word3.*word1|
word2.*word1.*word3|word3.*word2.*word1|word3.*word1.*word2)/i");`

But thats pretty herendous and you'd have to be crazy!, would be nicer to just use `strpos($haystack,$needle);` in a loop, or multiple regex matches.