# R - Find all vector elements that contain all strings / patterns - str_detect grep

Tags: r, stringr, grepl, and-operator

Sample data

```
files.in.path = c("a.4.0. name 2015 - NY.RDS", 
                  "b.4.0. name 2016 - CA.RDS", 
                  "c.4.0. name 2015 - PA.RDS")
strings.to.find = c("4.0", "PA")
```

I want the logical vector that shows all elements that contain all `strings.to.find`. The result wanted:

```
FALSE FALSE TRUE
```

This code will find elements that contain any one of the `strings.to.find`, i.e., uses an OR operator

```
str_detect(files.in.path, str_c(strings.to.find, collapse="|")) # OR operator
 TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

This code attempts to use an AND operator but does not work.

```
str_detect(files.in.path, str_c(strings.to.find, collapse="&")) # AND operator
FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

This works in several lines and I can write a `for` loop that will generate all the individual lines for cases with a larger number of `strings.to.find`

```
det.1 = str_detect(files.in.path,      "4.0"  )   
det.2 = str_detect(files.in.path,      "PA"  )   
det.all = det.1 & det.2
 FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

But is there a better way that does not involve using regex that depend on the position or order of the `strings.to.find`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A search of the web for either *'r regex "and operaror"'* or *'regex "and operator"'* lead to [R grep: is there an AND operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187414/r-grep-is-there-an-and-operator), and [Regular Expressions: Is there an AND operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator) respectively.

So to match both patterns concatenate the strings together

```
str <- paste0("(?=.*", strings.to.find,")", collapse="") 
grepl(str, files.in.path, perl=TRUE)
```

As Jota mentioned in comment by matching "4.0" this will also match other stings as the period is a metacharacter. One fix is to escape the period in your pattern string ie `strings.to.find = c( "PA", "4\\.0")`

Comment: @Jota; good point. example, `grepl("4.0", "4 0")`, so maybe we can escape it `grepl("4\\.0", "4 0")`

Answer (score 6):

This is not for heavy lifting, but `str_detect` is vectorized over both string and pattern, so you can combine it with `outer` function to get something close:

```
library(stringr)
outer(files.in.path, strings.to.find, str_detect)

#     [,1]  [,2]
#[1,] TRUE FALSE
#[2,] TRUE FALSE
#[3,] TRUE  TRUE
```

To check if all patterns exist in a string, `apply` the `all` logical operator per row of the resulting matrix:

```
apply(outer(files.in.path, strings.to.find, str_detect), 1, all)

#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Or as per @Jota commented, `stri_detect_fixed` will be safer to use here if the pattern you are looking at should be exactly matched:

```
library(stringi)
apply(outer(files.in.path, strings.to.find, stri_detect_fixed), 1, all)
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```