# How to grepl with two pattern objects in R

Tags: r, grepl

I have a vector called

```
vec <- c("16S_s95_S112_R2_101.fastq.gz",
         "16S_s95_S112_R1_001.fastq.gz",
         "16S_s94_S103_R2_021.fastq.gz",
         "16S_s94_S103_R1_001.fastq.gz")
```

I want to grepl items with `sample <- "_s95_"` and `R1 <- "R1"`.

I want to use `sample` and `R1` objects while doing grepl and find something matching `_s95_` and `R1` strings both.

Result I want is `16S_s95_S112_R1_001.fastq.gz`.
I tried `grepl(pattern = sample&R1, x= vec)` which did not work for me.

I can do this with multiple grepl's, but I am trying to find something neat to do this.

Comment: What are `sample` and `R1` ?

Comment: @JilberUrbina Not sure how it got deleted, but I have updated the question.

Comment: you need `grep(paste0(".*", sample, ".*", R1), vec, value=TRUE)`

Comment: I assume so, but just be sure: is it safe to assume that the sample pattern will always come before the R1 pattern?

Comment: @divibisan Yes, R1 follows sample, but it would be nice to see solution for any order.

Comment: Dupe-oid: [R grep: is there an AND operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187414/r-grep-is-there-an-and-operator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific use case where you know the order of the patterns, it's almost certainly going to be faster to follow [Jilber Urbina's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55801855/8366499) suggestion to programmatically compose a single regex.

For a more general solution that works regardless of order and on any number of patterns, we can use `sapply` to loop across each pattern, and then use `rowSums` to count the number of pattern matches and find the rows where all of them match:

```
patterns = c("_s95_", 'R1')

sapply(patterns, function(x) grepl(x, vec))
     _s95_    R1
[1,]  TRUE FALSE
[2,]  TRUE  TRUE
[3,] FALSE FALSE
[4,] FALSE  TRUE

vec[which(rowSums(sapply(patterns, function(x) grepl(x, vec))) == length(patterns))]

[1] "16S_s95_S112_R1_001.fastq.gz"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to work a bit more in your pattern in order to get the match, try:

```
> grep(paste0(".*", sample, ".*", R1), vec, value=TRUE)
[1] "16S_s95_S112_R1_001.fastq.gz"
```