# multiple pattern in list.files() in R

Tags: r

`list.files(pattern="a|b")`
gives me a list with file names that has an a or b in the name.

I would like to have a
`list.files(pattern="a&b")`
that gives me a list with file names that has an a **and** b in the name. But this doesnt work.

Is there a solution with a metacharacter that has a logical "and" meaning?
Or another solution?

Comment: Related: [R grep: is there an AND operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187414/r-grep-is-there-an-and-operator)

Comment: @Max That will only work if “a” precedes “b”. You could make two such patterns with “b” first and put a “|” between them to cover the reversal option

Comment: @IRTFM yes,  list.files(pattern=".*a.*b|.*b.*a") is the safer way

Comment: Also. The leading “.*” in those two pattern is not neeeded.

Comment: you're right!    list.files(pattern="a.*b|b.*a")    is enough