# Regular expression for x number of digits and only one hyphen?

Tags: asp.net, xml, regex

I made the following regex:

```
(\d{5}|\d-\d{4}|\d{2}-\d{3}|\d{3}-\d{2}|\d{4}-\d)
```

And it seems to work.  That is, it will match a 5 digit number or a 5 digit number with only 1 hyphen in it, but the hyphen can not be the lead or the end.

I would like a similar regex, but for a 25 digit number.  If I use the same tactic as above, the regex will be very long.

Can anyone suggest a simpler regex?

Additional Notes:
I'm putting this regex into an XML file which is to be consumed by an ASP.NET application.  I don't have access to the .net backend code.  But I suspect they would do something liek this:

```
Match match = Regex.Match("Something goes here", "my regex", RegexOptions.None);
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a regular expression?

Comment: @RohitJain i added more notes in response to your comments

Comment: @John. I would suggest not to use regex here. It's not a regex task.

Comment: Oh ok, i don't have access to any code behind.  The specification document only allows me to enter regex into the templated XML file I've been given.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use a lookahead:

```
^(?:\d{25}|(?=\d+-\d+$)[\d\-]{26})$
```

Explanation:

- Either it's `\d{25}` from start to end, 25 digits.
- Or: it is 26 characters of `[\d\-]` (digits or hyphen) [AND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041320/regex-and-operator) it matched `\d+-\d+` - meaning it has exactly one hyphen in the middle.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Working example with test cases](http://www.debuggex.com/r/7mf1H0hbW9t3NWZD/0)

Comment: Here's another version using the stack for counting, and having the number 25 only once: `^(?<Digit>\d)+(?:-(?<Digit>\d)+)?$(?<-Digit>){25}(?(Digit)(?!))`

Comment: This will match 25 digits with zero hyphens as well.

Comment: @pguardiario - It sure will. Isn't that what the OP wanted? John had `\d{5}` as the first alternation.

Answer (score 5):

You could use this regex:

```
^[0-9](?:(?=[0-9]*-[0-9]*$)[0-9-]{24}|[0-9]{23})[0-9]$
```

The lookahead makes sure there's only 1 dash and the character class makes sure there are 23 numbers between the first and the last. Might be made shorter though I think.

EDIT: The a 'bit' shorter xP

```
^(?:[0-9]{25}|(?=[^-]+-[^-]+$)[0-9-]{26})$
```

A bit similar to Kobi's though, I admit.

Comment: I don't know anything about the asp.net regex engine. But does it support infinite length lookaheads?

Comment: @FDinoff Yup! Sure does.

Comment: @FDinoff - are there Regex flavors that don't support variable length lookaheads? I know lookbehinds are not usually supported (.net has these too, by the way).

Comment: thakns guys!  i like it, I picked kobi's because he gave me a pretty picture

Comment: @Kobi I don't know. I just assumed if variable length look behinds weren't supported in some languages lookaheads wouldn't be either. Bad assumption on my part I guess

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't fussy about the length at all (i.e. you only want a string of digits with an optional hyphen) you could use:

```
([\d]+-[\d]+){1}|\d
```

(You may want to add line/word boundaries to this, depending on your circumstances)

If you need to have a specific length of match, this pattern doesn't really work. Kobi's answer is probably a better fit for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the fastest way is to do a simple match then add up the length of the capture buffers, why attempt math in a regex, makes no sence.

```
 ^(\d+)-?(\d+)$
```

Answer (score 0):

This will match 25 digits and exactly one hyphen in the middle:

```
^(?=(-*\d){25})\d.{24}\d$
```

Comment: Did you test your pattern? Aside from *not* matching `^\d{25}$`, it also matches 26 digits.

Comment: @Kobi - I'm not sure that's right but see my update for a simpler way to do that.