# Salesforce REGEX - Detect Chars not working as expected

Tags: regex, salesforce, java-6

I have the following situation in Salesforce: A certain fields contains one string. But this string char's all have a significant meaning.

For instance, the string can look like: GHJKL where G, H, J, ... have a certain meaning which is being used in code.

What I would like to do now is perform a Validation on the entered String with following conditions:

- Only the chars: **GHJKL** can be entered
- The char G AND/OR H must be entered ***at east once***

I have following REGEX which detects that only the above chars can be entered:

- For the first Validation:

  'NOT(REGEX(CustomFieldName__c,"[ABCDEI]{0,30}"))'
- For the Second Validation:

  'NOT(REGEX(CustomFieldName__c,"[DE]{1,}"))'

But the second validation seems not be working. I've tested the Regex using online Regex tester where this seems to be working. But on Salesforce, the regex is constantly providing a False.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be regex for second validation for You

```
(?=.*D)(?=.*E).*|[DE]+
```

Thanks to [Regex AND operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041320/regex-and-operator)

Comment: Thanks! I altered your code a bit to the following which suited my needs: `(?=.*D).*|(?=.*E).*|[DE]+`