# Regex AND Operator not working

Tags: regex

According to the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041320/regex-and-operator) on Stack OverFlow:

> (?=.*foo)(?=.*baz) 
>  
>   This says to the regular expression that foo must appear anywhere and baz must appear anywhere, not necessarily in that order and possibly overlapping.

This regular expression should match those words **foo** and **baz**:

```
Where foo have baz all my life
```

However this doesn't work. Nor in [regexr](http://regexr.com/3b6di) nor in [regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com/).

Comment: Something like: https://regex101.com/r/rS8sK6/1 ?

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ: Excellent! Can you explain to me the expression, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a capture group around `foo` and `baz` because the lookaround isn't a capture group, but an assertion.

> **The lookahead itself is not a capturing group**. It is not included in the count towards numbering the backreferences. **If you want to store the match of the regex inside a lookahead, you have to put capturing parentheses around the regex inside the lookahead**, like this: (?=(regex)). The other way around will not work, because the lookahead will already have discarded the regex match by the time the capturing group is to store its match.

<sup>http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html</sup>

Make your regular expression:

```
(?=.+?(foo))(?=.+?(baz))
```

Note the capture group within the lookahead.

https://regex101.com/r/rS8sK6/1

Comment: That's because of the positive lookahead. It requires at least one character before (because I made the quantifier become `+?` - *my bad*). If you change the `+?` after the `.`, to quantifier `*` then it will: https://regex101.com/r/rS8sK6/2

Comment: Thanks. All works now. Any idea why http://regexpal.com/ doesn't work for this expression?

Comment: No worries. Glad to help. I've never used regexpal.com, so I'm unsure. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

Lookarounds are only assertions which won't match any single character.

```
(?=.*foo)(?=.*baz)
```

asserts that the line where the match going to happend must contain  `foo` and `baz` strings. And i suggest you to use anchors along with the above lookarounds.

```
^(?=.*foo)(?=.*baz)
```

This would the boundary which exists at the start of a line.

> Where the above regex would be helpful?

This is helpful when you want to print the whole line where the strings `foo` and `baz` appears.

In js, you could write

```
/^(?=.*foo)(?=.*baz)/m.test(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are only two strings you are looking for, you can do:

(XXX.*YYY)|(YYY.*XXX)

It will search for XXX and YYY in the same line in both orders.

Maybe not efficient but it is simple and works.