# Boolean Text Search in R

Tags: r, search, boolean

How do I do full boolean text search in R?  I am using str_match which works only with OR or | operator, or I use Reduce function with &.  Is there a way to do AND, OR and XOR seamlessly for text search in R?

Comment: Please include a specific example.

Comment: An `and` for regex might be impossible, have a look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041320/regex-and-operator) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator).  I think you need regex's `lockahead` and `lockbehind`.

Comment: `library(stringi)` supports using `&` in char classes.  For more info, read `help("stringi-search-charclass", package = "stringi")`

Comment: Thank you SabDem and Richard Scriven.  I will read the resources.

Answer (score -1):

consider using the [rlucene](https://github.com/s-u/RLucene) package which connects to the [lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/) search library which provides full-text search including a BooleanQuery which siport AND OR and NOT.

Comment: Thank you Oren Bochman.  Will try rlucene.  Guess I have a steep learning curve ahead.