# Boolean & wildcard text matching

Tags: r, boolean-logic, text-analysis

Is anyone aware of any R package that supports complex boolean + wildcard text matching implemented in some web interfaces - i.e. using `AND` `OR` `*` `?` `()`/`{}` operators?  For example a function that can handle queries in the following formats (all examples return TRUE):

```
s = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
boolean_match(s, "fox AND dog")
boolean_match(s, "fox OR bird")
boolean_match(s, "f?x")
boolean_match(s, "The quick * dog")
boolean_match(s, "lazy AND (fox OR bird)") # i.e. nested logic
boolean_match(s, "(pretty AND bird) OR (quick AND (fox OR squirrel))") # recursive
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32124185/boolean-text-search-in-) asks the same but has not received much interest.  I'm aware of the `stringi` package - e.g. `stri_detect_regex(s, c("fox","dog"))`, potentially combined with `all()`/`any()` - but it seems unable to handle the nested logic.  Attempting conversion of this sort of complex query structure to REGEX seems suicidal.

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: Would using a structure such as `if(grepl("fox", s) == TRUE & grepl("dog", s) == TRUE)` or `if(grepl("fox", s) == TRUE | grepl("dog", s) == TRUE)` work for what you are attempting to accomplish?

Comment: Restructuring you statements using `any()` / `all()` like this would provide nested evaluation `all(stri_detect_regex(s,"lazy"), all(stri_detect_regex(s,"quick"), any(stri_detect_regex(s,"fox"), stri_detect_regex(s,"dog"))))`

Comment: Thanks Matt. I'm looking for a general solution, i.e. not one where I have to string these functions together. Let's see if anyone else has a suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written something myself - see https://github.com/geotheory/booleanR