# Filtering Pandas dataframe rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that has one column **numbers**. The column's data are strings of numbers separated by commas.

```
numbers
-------
1,3,4,5,17,30
5,6,18,37,41,42
1,2,5,14,19,20
1,5,13,20,29,31
1,9,10,11,14,17
2,9,13,25,30,35
```

How to get all the strings that contain numbers **1** & **5** only?

The desired output:

```
numbers
-------
1,3,4,5,17,30
1,2,5,14,19,20
1,5,13,20,29,31
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create `df` by [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and compare with [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) with [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for both condition. Last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df['numbers'].str.split(',', expand=True).astype(int)
df = df[df1.eq(1).any(1) & df1.eq(5).any(1)]
print (df)
           numbers
0    1,3,4,5,17,30
2   1,2,5,14,19,20
3  1,5,13,20,29,31
```

Another solution with [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) for conditions:

```
a = df['numbers'].str.contains(',1,|,1$|^1,')
b = df['numbers'].str.contains(',5,|,5$|^5,')

df = df[a & b]
print (df)
           numbers
0    1,3,4,5,17,30
2   1,2,5,14,19,20
3  1,5,13,20,29,31
```

Comment: using contains can we filter the data using one regex

Comment: yes, if need `1` or `5`. but if need `1` and `5` I think not.

Comment: what I meant was, can we write one regular expression that filter all strings that contain 1 and 5 at the same time.

Comment: `df1.eq(1).any(1) & df1.eq(5).any(1)` could be replaced with `df1.isin([1,5]).any(1)`, no?

Comment: @IanS - I think not, because isin is `1 or 5`. So get different output.

Comment: @HmH - I think it is not possible check it [same time in regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3041326/2901002), because need  `AND`, not `OR`