# Use non-consuming regular expression in pySpark sql functions

Tags: regex, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How can I use existing pySpark sql functions to find non-consuming regular expression patterns in a string column?

The following is reproducible, but does not give the desired results.

```py
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import (
    SparkSession,
    functions as F)

spark = (SparkSession.builder
         .master('yarn')
         .appName("regex")
         .getOrCreate()
         )

sc = spark.sparkContext
sc.version # u'2.2.0'

testdf = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, "Julie", "CEO"),
    (2, "Janice", "CFO"),
    (3, "Jake", "CTO")],
    ["ID", "Name", "Title"])
```

```py
ptrn = '(?=Ja)(?=ke)'
```

```py
testdf.withColumn('contns_ptrn', testdf.Name.rlike(ptrn) ).show()
```

```
+---+------+-----+-----------+
| ID|  Name|Title|contns_ptrn|
+---+------+-----+-----------+
|  1| Julie|  CEO|      false|
|  2|Janice|  CFO|      false|
|  3|  Jake|  CTO|      false|
+---+------+-----+-----------+
```

```py
testdf.withColumn('contns_ptrn', F.regexp_extract(F.col('Name'), ptrn, 1)).show()
```

```
+---+------+-----+-----------+
| ID|  Name|Title|contns_ptrn|
+---+------+-----+-----------+
|  1| Julie|  CEO|           |
|  2|Janice|  CFO|           |
|  3|  Jake|  CTO|           |
+---+------+-----+-----------+
```

```py
testdf.withColumn('contns_ptrn', F.regexp_replace(F.col('Name'), ptrn, '')).show()
```

```
+---+------+-----+-----------+
| ID|  Name|Title|contns_ptrn|
+---+------+-----+-----------+
|  1| Julie|  CEO|      Julie|
|  2|Janice|  CFO|     Janice|
|  3|  Jake|  CTO|       Jake|
+---+------+-----+-----------+
```

The desired results would be:

```
+---+------+-----+-----------+
| ID|  Name|Title|contns_ptrn|
+---+------+-----+-----------+
|  1| Julie|  CEO|      false|
|  2|Janice|  CFO|      false|
|  3|  Jake|  CTO|       true|
+---+------+-----+-----------+
```

As the third row in the Name column contains 'Ja' *and* 'ke'.

If `regexp_extract` or `regexp_replace` are able to extract or replace non-consuming regular expression patterns, then I could also use them together with `length` to get a Boolean column.

Answer (score 0):

Found a quick solution, hopefully this can help someone else.

change `ptrn` from `'(?=Ja)(?=ke)'` to `'(?=.*Ja)(?=.*ke)'` and `rlike` works.

This answer got me close, but led to my problem. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/469951/5060792

These answers solved my problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3041326
https://stackoverflow.com/a/470602/5060792

By the way, with nothing but the change to `ptrn`, `regexp_extract` throws a `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 1` exception. After wrapping the entire pattern in parenthesis, `ptrn = '((?=.*Ja)(?=.*ke))'`, it returns nulls.

Again, `regexp_replace` replaces nothing and the original values are returned.

Comment: There is no such thing as a _`a non-consuming regular expression`_. There is no documentation that lists this as anything at all.

Comment: Got that terminology from https://stackoverflow.com/a/469951/5060792.  Same as a 'Positive lookahead', wherein several references say something along the lines of Positive lookahead patterns do 'not consume any characters or expand the match.'  So: do not consume, non-consuming, and the included `(?='pattern')` - clear enough.

Comment: No, not really. To be clear, _Assertions do not consume characters_. It is an attribute of these constructs. It includes BOS, EOS, Anchors, neg/pos lookbehinds, word boundary and others. `^$\A\Z\z\G\b\B(?=)(?<=)(?!)(?<!)` etc... It's a stretch to think _`a non-consuming regular expression`_ has any specific quantifiable meaning, get my drift ?