# regex AND operator with negative arguments

Tags: regex, jedit, and-operator

I'm trying to match lines that doesn't end with either `.` or `!` and doesn't end with either `."` or `!"` so it should match both

- `say "bye"`
- `say "bye`

but shouldn't match:

- `say "bye.`
- `say "bye!`
- `say "bye."`
- `say "bye!"`

I tried using positive and negative lookahead, trying to use them as AND as suggested in [Regex AND operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041320/regex-and-operator), but I can't make it work, nor I'm sure it's feasible with lookaheads.

Comment: what will be desired result for strings like `say "bye".` should it match ?

Comment: You can try something like this [`^(?!.*[.!]"?$).*$`](https://regex101.com/r/BvFegP/1/)

Comment: It should match any line that doesn't end with . or ! or ." or !" so ```say "bye".``` shouldn't match. Your suggestion seems to work, I'll test it further and study it to understand what it does; thanks!

Comment: Why do you think jEdit has no lookbehind? Of course it has, it has all that Java supports, lookbehind included.

Comment: Because in jEdit's user guide's page about regex lookaheads are listed, but lookbehinds are not, so I thought it didn't had them: http://www.jedit.org/users-guide/regexps.html

Comment: Not all details are listed, that's why the link above is provided.
I added lookbehinds now to the docs for the next version though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a negative lookbehind.
This matches exactly what you asked for: `^.*+(?<![.!]"?)$`

---

`^` - beginning of line
`.*+` - any amount of characters, not giving up for backtracking
`(?<!` + `)` - not preceded by
`[.!]` - dot or exclamation mark
`"?` - optional double-quote
`$` - end of line

Comment: And is much more efficient, the lookahead variant has to match the whole string twice. My version needs for a matching line that is x characters long always `6` steps in the regex engine, the lookahead variant needs `x * 2 + 6` steps. And my (now slightly improved) version needs for a non-matching line always `5` steps in the regex engine, the lookahead variant needs `10` steps.

Comment: What does it mean "not giving up for backtracking"?

Comment: It is a possessive quantifier, meaning once it matched something it won't give up characters to somehow find a match that makes the regex match. Read more about it at https://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html. Without the `+` for a non-matching line the engine would first match all characters and see whether then comes the end not preceded by dot or exclamation mark and optional double-quote. As this is not the case, the non-possessive `*` would give up one character and the same check is done. But as this can never match, we can use the possessive quantifier there.

Comment: @Vampire where did you tested this regex this shows pattern error to me [`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/IMcn4E/2)

Comment: @CodeManiac we are talking about Java regexes. With what you linked you can only test PHP, JavaScript, Python and Golang regexes. Each flavor has its specifics. For PHP you could for example write `^.*+(?<![.!]|[.!]")$` to have it valid.

Comment: @Vampire oh i see i consider generally `perl` regex as one of most advanced regex so i didn't knew java has this functionality of dynamic length lookbehind, any recommended tool to test java regex performance online ?

Comment: I used evaluation version of RegexBuddy as I was curious. You also have to keep in mind that PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) are not the same as Perl regular expressions, especially when it comes to lookbehind. In Perl all options have to have the same length. In PCRE they may have different lengths (but obviously not with quantifiers). In Java the maximum size just has to be able to be calculated and be in some bounds, but you can e. g. use `{,9999999}` instead of `*` if you can estimate it is enough and so on.

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
^(?!.*[.!]"?$).*$
```

[image]

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/BvFegP/2)

***Note:-*** This matches empty line too as we use `*` which means match anything zero or more time, if you want to avoid empty lines to match you can use `+` quantifier which means match one or more time

Comment: This works, but is pretty inefficient. Using negative lookbehind should be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure `bye` isn't succeeded by `.` or `!` with a positive look-ahead for a negative character class, and then make the last `"` optional with the `?` quantifier:

```
\bsay "bye(?=[^.!])"?
```

Comment: How can I make it work for any line, not just the example one? I tried ```^.+(?=[^.!])"?```, but it doesn't work. Edit: Code Maniac's suggestion seems to work, I'm testing it.

Comment: I'm assuming `jEdit`'s search-replace feature has a "Replace All" function?

Comment: Yes, it does have it.

Comment: This version would not match a line ending on `bye` like the second example in the question, as it always needs one character after the `bye` that is not a dot or exclamation mark. Additionally the regex does not test for the end of string.