# Using str.contains to look for two substrings with pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm afraid the solution is obvious or the question a duplicate, but I couldn't find an answer yet: I have a pandas data frame that contains long strings and I need two strings to be matched at the same time. I found the "or" version multiple time but I didn't find the "and" solution yet.

Please assume the following data frame where the interesting information "element type" and subpart type" are separated by a random in between element:

```py
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({"col1":["element1_random_string_subpartA"
                           , "element2_ran_str_subpartA"
                           , "element1_some_text_subpartB"
                           , "element2_some_other_text_subpartB"]})
```

I'd now like to filter for all lines that contain element1 and subpartA.

```py
data.col1.str.contains("element1|subpartA")
```

return a data frame

```
True 
True
True
False
```

which is the expected result. But I need an "And" combination and

```py
data.col1.str.contains("element1&subpartA")
```

returns

```
False
False
False
False
```

although I'd expect

```
True
False 
False
False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Regex and`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3041326) is not easy:

```
m = data.col1.str.contains(r'(?=.*subpartA)(?=.*element1)')
```

Simplier is chain both conditions with `&` for bitwise `AND`:

```
m = data.col1.str.contains("subpartA") & data.col1.str.contains("element1")
print (m)
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
Name: col1, dtype: bool
```

Comment: yeah, quite obvious there is an obvious way. thanks. Nonetheless: any idea why the "|" works but not "&"?