# Regular expression AND operator in .net framework

Tags: c#, .net

You can do this in Perl/Java ( [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator) )

Is it possible to do this in c#?

Comment: Have you tried? What results did you observe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do that in C#. It's called a [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). See [this table](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html) for a comparison of the capabilities of various regular expression engines (search for lookaround on that page).

On a related note, C# also supports variable width lookbehind assertions - something that most other engines do not support.