# .Net AND operator Regular Expression using strings in a document

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Say I have a situation where I need to search for the word 'Foo' in a document but I only want it to match if the word 'Bar' appears anywhere else in that document (i.e. 'Bar' can be on the same line, a different line, before or after 'Foo').  Can I use a Regular Expression to do this?

Following the link in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538976/regular-expression-and-operator-in-net-framework) SE post, I've tried:

```
Foo(?=.*\nBar)|Foo(?=.*Bar)|Foo(?<!.*Bar)|Foo(?<!.*\nBar)
```

which works great if Foo is missing, but it still selects Foo even if Bar is missing. I've also checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator) SE post, but all the answers speak of Java/Perl, and do not work using .NET.

Is it possible to accomplish this using Regular Expressions in .NET, or do I need to resort to using a C# && operator in the code itself?

Comment: what's wrong with `str.Contains("Foo") && str.Contains("Bar")`?

Comment: Why do only want to use regular expressions?  Are you using some sort of control that takes in a regex as a validation or something?

Comment: @DStanley I am using regular expressions in place of each string Foo and Bar.  I just used string for clarity of the question as the actual regex expressions are very complex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you are asking:  do you want to return a match only if "foo" and "bar" are both in the document?  If so, then

```
(?>.*foo.*bar)|(?>.*bar.*foo)
```

works pretty well.  Then in C# .Net use RegexOptions.Singleline so that the "." does not stop at an "\n".

Code example:

```
        string text = @"blah blah bar foo bar";
        string pattern = @"(?>.*foo.*bar)|(?>.*bar.*foo)";
        Match match = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline).Match(text);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            // do something
        }
```

But if that is what you want, then using the string contains method is much simpler.

EDIT:
Based on your new comment, try this regex, using a named capture group to just capture the number:

```
((?<CCNum>4\d{3}[ -]?(\d{4}[ -]?){2}\d{4}).*Bar)|(.*Bar.*(?<CCNum>4\d{3}[ -]?(\d{4}[ -]?){2}\d{4}))
```

And usage:

```
        string text = @"Bar 4111-1111 1111 1111";
        string pattern = @"((?<CCNum>4\d{3}[ -]?(\d{4}[ -]?){2}\d{4}).*Bar)|(.*Bar.*(?<CCNum>4\d{3}[ -]?(\d{4}[ -]?){2}\d{4}))";
        long CCNum;
        Match match = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline).Match(text);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            if (Int64.TryParse (match.Groups["CCNum"].Value.Replace(" ", "").Replace("-",""),out CCNum));
            {
                // here is your clean CC Number
            }


        }
```

Comment: thanks so much it's really close.  The only thing is I need it to select only the credit card number instead of both Bar and the CC Number (or anything in between).

Comment: That is why I defined the named capture group CCNum--It just gets the number.  Then in your code, access the Match.Groups["CCNum"].Value property (or something very similar; just going from off the cuff here).  Bar is matched but not captured.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your question, your code is almost good.

Try this :

```
    Foo(?=.*Bar)|Foo(?<=Bar.*)
```

It means :

```
Select from 2 alternatives :
    - Foo, then match a suffix (.*Bar) but exclude it from the capture
    - Foo, with a prefix (Bar.*) but exclude it from the capture
```

Hope it helps :-)

Comment: yes thank you.  I just added the C# Singleline Option to account for multiple lines and it works perfectly

Comment: Edit: sorry not sure if I should make a new question for this, but this does work with Foo Bar, but not quite with what I actually need which is a regex and a word: 4\d{3}([\ \-]?)\d{4}\1\d{4}\1\d{4}(?=.*Bar)|4\d{3}([\ \-]?)\d{4}\1\d{4}\1\d{4}(?<=Bar.*).  The regex checks for a Credit Card number.  This works fine when it's a credit card number in front of Bar, but not when Bar is behind the CC#.  Ex: Bar 4111 1111 1111 1111.  Any thoughts?

Comment: your regex just posted will not work with your example, because if the first numbered capture does not succeed, then the alternate regex using that back-reference will also fail