# regexp logic and or

Tags: javascript, regex

I know there are logical operators such as `|` "the OR operator" which can be used like this:

```
earth|world
```

I was wondering how I could check if my string contains earth AND world.

regards,
alexander

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If it contains `earth` AND `world`, it contains one after the other, so:

```
earth.*world|world.*earth
```

A shorter alternative (using extended regex syntax) would be:

```
/^(?=.*?earth)(?=.*?world)/
```

But it is not at all like an `and` operator. You can only do `or` because if only one of the words is included, there is no ordering involved. If you want to have them both, you need to indicate the order.

Comment: I wouldn't call the second version hackish - on the contrary, especially if more than two conditions are involved, I find sequential lookaheads much more straightforward.

Answer (score 6):

do two tests, if the first fails the second doesn't execute in javascript. e.g.

```
var hasBoth = /earth/i.test(aString) && /world/i.test(aString);
```

Comment: not always convenient, would be nice to know how to do this with one regex

Answer (score 5):

This question was asked and answered here:

[Regular Expressions: Is there an AND operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator)

There isn't a direct "and" operator, but you can continue expression testing and ensure the second expression is also a match.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need & operator actually | operator does the job

```js
let string = 'world and earth are awesome';
let regex = /world|earth/ig;

let result = string.replace(regex, '...');

console.log(string);
console.log(result);
```