# How to use match two cases using regular expression?

Tags: regex

Given a sentence,

> Scheme **is** such a bizarre programming **language**.

So any sentence that contains `is` and `language` should return true. I found `|` means `or`, but couldn't find any symbol means `and`.

Thanks,

Comment: "ab" means "a" and then "b".  Now you know and.

Comment: @tchrist: Thanks. But if I put `islanguage`, how does regex know i mean a whole word, or two separate words?

Comment: You don't need regular expressions to find such strings (although a regular expression is guaranteed to exist because [regular languages are closed under intersection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language#Closure_properties) and the sets of strings that have "is" or "language" as substrings are regular).  You could just perform two substring searches.  Is it a requirement that "is" appear before "language"?

Comment: It knows if you say "something and then is and the something and then language and then something", thus more than one and.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the idiom.

```
(?=expr)
```

For example,

```
(?=.*word1)(?=.*word2)
```

For more details, please refer to [this threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator).

Answer (score 3):

Try the following regex:

```
\bis\b.*\blanguage\b
```

This one will match if the two words appear in exactly that order. \b (word boundary) means that the words are standalone.

Comment: @Chan What language do you use? Try e.g. ".*\bis\b.*\blanguage\b.*" or ".*\\bis\\b.*\\blanguage\\b.*"

Comment: I'm using Scheme with DrScheme.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda ugly, but it should work (regardless of the how 'is' and 'language' are ordered):

```
(.*is.*language.*|.*language.*is.*)
```

Comment: The answer from @jumperchen is much better than mine!

Answer (score 0):

In c# (and I know you didn't ask about c#, but it illustrates how this can be done much quicker)...

```
 string s = "Scheme is such a bizarre programming language.";
 if ((s.Contains(" is") || s.Contains("is ")) &&  
     (s.Contains(" language") || s.Contains("language ")))
 {
    // found match if you got here
 }
```

Regexs can be slow and hard to parse by someone who is reading your code. Simple string matches are quicker generally.

EDIT: This doesn't care about the order of the words and works for simple whitespace only

Answer (score 0):

Try this one if you don't care about the order of the words in the sentence:

```
\bis\b.*\blanguage\b|\blanguage\b.*\bis\b
```

Comment: Thanks but I do care about the order.