# AND operator in regular expressions

Tags: java, regex

I've searched for a while how to use logical operation AND in regular expressions in Java, and have failed.
I've tried to do as recommended in similar topic:

```
(?=match this expression)(?=match this too)(?=oh, and this)
```

and it doesn't work.  Even simple examples with ?= returns false:

```
String b = "aaadcd";
System.out.println(b.matches("(?=aa.*)"));
```

Also I've read that `(expression X)(expression Y)` should work like `X AND Y`, but it works like `X OR Y`.
What am I doing wrong?

Added:
Tried to add `.*` in the end. Still don't work.
For a example:

`[2-9]?[0-9]{5,9}||1[2-9][0-9]{1,2}||120[0-9]{1,1}||119[0-9]` = X  - return false if number is less than 1190

`[0-9]{1,3}||1[0-0][0-9]{1,2}||11[0-8][0-9]{1,1}||119[0-2]` = Y - return false if number is greater than 1992.

```
String a = "1189";
a.matches(X) // return false
a.mathes(Y)  // return true
a.matches((?=X)(?=Y).*) // return true, but should return false.
```

Added:
Yep, my regexp is not correct. My bad. The problem solved. Thank everyone very much!

Comment: `(expression X)(expression Y)` works like "expression X THEN expression Y".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular Expressions: Is there an AND operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator)

Comment: Your regex are wrong: all of the match the empty strings (because you use `||`) and the first one matches `121`, for example. Re-check each part of your regex, please.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think what you need is `(?=X)Y`

- `(?=X)` matches X, without consuming it (zero-width)
- `Y` and matches Y

The main problem: X and Y are wrong, they should be (assuming 4 digits):

X: `119[0-9]|1[2-9][0-9]{2}|[2-9][0-9]{3}`

- 1190-1199, or
- 1200-1999, or
- 2000-9999

Y: `1[0-8][0-9]{2}|19[0-8][0-9]|199[0-2]`

- 1000-1899, or
- 1900-1980, or
- 1990-1992

Here a test code:

```
// X - return false if number is less than 1190
String X = "119[0-9]|1[2-9][0-9]{2}|[2-9][0-9]{3}"; 

// Y - return false if number is greater than 1992.
String Y = "1[0-8][0-9]{2}|19[0-8][0-9]|199[0-2]";

String pattern = "(?=" + X + ")" + Y;

String values = "1000 1100 1180 1189 1190 1191 1199 1200 1290 1900 1980 1989 " +
                "1990 1991 1992 1993 1999 2000 3000 2991 9999";
for (String string : values.split(" ")) {
    System.out.printf("\"%s\" %s%n", string, string.matches(pattern));
}
```

Comment: +1 for the full analysis of the updated question. I was too lazy for that ;-)

Answer (score 7):

`(?=` **does** work.

What you're doing wrong is that you're using `matches` but your regex doesn't match anything.

`(?=` is a [zero-width positive look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html): it doesn't "consume" any characters, but just verifies that its position is followed by something that matches its content.

So *either* replace your [`matches()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) call with [`Matcher.find()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) *or* make sure that your have something in your regex that matches the entire string (`.*` is a common candidate).

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. But still don't work. I updated the post with the example.

Answer (score 1):

As Joachim answered, add a `.*` in the end:

```
String b = "aaadcd";
System.out.println(b.matches("(?=aaa)(?=.*dcd).*"));
// => true

String b = "aaaxxx";
System.out.println(b.matches("(?=aaa)(?=.*dcd).*"));
// => false
```