# Need help for combining two regex conditions using something like AND operator

Tags: java, regex

I have two conditions in my regular expression.
  Say,

1. `(.*text.*)`    ---> which will check whether the input string has the substring "text" in it.
2. `(^((?!query).)*$)`    ----> which will check whether the input string does not contains the word "query" int it.

Both are working fine for me.

But I want a regular expression to check both the conditions using something like `AND` operator.

I want a regex which should return true only if the input string contains the substring "text" and does not contains "query" in it.

I got the info that regex does not support `AND` operator.
So, I tried to do something like the following:

```
NOT(NOT(expression 1)|(NOT(expression 2)))
```

eg:- `(!(.*query.*)|(^((?!text).)*$))`

But even this does not work for me..

Anyone please help me regarding this.

Comment: Java or Javascript or both? It's not the same.
If it's just static texts you want to check, why not use "contains": (!stringToCheck.contains(text) && !stringToCheck.contains(query))

Comment: Apparently the target flavor is Java.  I removed the other tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a non-consuming regular expression.

The typical  notation is:

`(?=expr)`

This means *match expr* but after that continue matching at the original match-point.

You can do as many of these as you want, and this will be an "**and**".

**Syntax Eg:**

`(?=match this expression)(?=match this too)(?=oh, and this)`

**Update:-**

Need to add `.*` incase `matches()` is used so that regex matches the entire string.

Your regex will be `str.matches("(?=(.*text.*))(?=(^((?!query).)*$)).*")`

Comment: This is not an "and", this is just a concatenation. How could you evaluate "someString" to false with this, when text=meSt and query=meSt?

Comment: @Adrian - Here is a reference for more a detailed [explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185438/and-operator-in-regular-expressions)

Comment: Thanks R.J, I tried (?=(.*text.*))(?=(^((?!query).)*$)) but it is not working for me. Sorry I am a novice in regex. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: happy to help :) accept the answer if it served your purpose!

Comment: @R.J Thanks for your help.. It is working if we use str.matches  but the code is like "matcher = regexp.matcher(str);" and when using "matcher.find()" in if condition it is not working :(
I could not modify the code.

Comment: It should be `matcher.matches()` and not `matcher.find()`.

Comment: @R.J The actual problem is i have to find a word which matches the above regex and i have to redirect to some other url in my application server. So, i need the to get the word which matches the regex from the incoming URL (which will be typically enclosed with /). That is why we are using matcher.find(). And the problem is the code cannot be modified now whereas i can only modify the input string (the URL in my case) and the regex pattern. :(

Comment: `String str = "textquer";
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?=(.*text.*))(?=(^((?!query).)*$)).*");
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
  if (matcher.find())
  {
   // The below String has the text which matches this pattern.
      String result = matcher.group(1);
      System.out.println(result);
  }`