# How to write a regexp with AND operator?

Tags: c++, regex, boost-regex

I have definition string from my user to match an input string and i would like to simplify the definition string so my user won't need to know regexp internal.

my thought was to allow `*/-7721/-7722/-7723` to match any given 4 digit string which is `not 7721 AND not 7722 AND not 7723`.

I am searching for a regexp to perform the above on an input string which is a 4 digit number.

I have tried using the `?!` notation, but it can't mis-match the entire string.

`(?![0-9]{4})` - this doesn't allow any 4 digit string.

`((?!(7721))(?!(7722))(?!(77223))` - this also didn't work

Is there an AND operator to perform the above?

Thanks,

Comment: In which programming language? Since these are numbers, can you use mathematics, rather than string operations?

Comment: @Johnsyweb: actually C++ boost regexp. let me update my tags. How can i use maths? (sorry for asking)?

Comment: ?= perhaps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator

Comment: `int i = boost::lexical_cast<int>(s);
return i < 10000 && i != 7721 && i != 7722 && i != 7723;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot ^:

```
^(?!(?:7721))(?!(?:7722))(?!(?:7723))\d{4}
```

Edited: added \d{4} for actually matching the string, not just testing

Comment: What do you mean? Do you actually need to match the string, or merely test it?

Comment: The non-capturing subpatterns are unnecessary; also, this example can be simplified to `^(?!772[1-3])\d{4}$`.