# regular expressions regex how to make "and"

Tags: c#, regex, split, find

I have a text and want to find some strings with regular expressions. My problem is i don't know how to make "&&-and" here.

I have text like this:

```
AB " something is here;
  and here...
";
...
AB "new line 
 continues ... ";
```

I want to find all AB, which end with ";

My code i use for ";" :

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(tmp, "(AB) ([^;]*);", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

But how can i make  `"(AB) ([^(\";)]*)\";"` or just `"(AB) ([^(\"&&;)]*)(\"&&;")` ?

I would like to have:

```
AB

" something is here;
 and here ...
"

AB
"new line
 continues ..."
```

Comment: And what exactly do you want to match? Could you perhaps show an example block of text, and then the part you want matched?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^` can only negate character classes, which in turn cannot contain strings of characters (but only single characters). However, there is a similar concept for strings of characters (or in fact full-fledged regular expressions) called a negative lookahead:

```
@"(AB) (\"(?:(?!\";).)*\");"
```

This will now consume arbitrary characters (`.`) as long as they do not mark the start of a `";`. Keep using the `Singleline` option, of course. You can do some reading on [lookaround assertions here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: please see my edit, what i want to achive. I tried your code but gives me some errors with @"AB ?

Comment: @UniLe note that I my snippet is not a regex but the full regex-string (as a verbatim string, which should always be used for regular expressions). if you want to capture the two parts separately, you can just add parentheses: `"(AB) (\"(?:(?!\";).)*\");"`. However, this is a bit pointless in your case, because the first two characters of your match will always be `AB` and the characters from index `3` to the second-to-last index, will be the rest.

Comment: @m.buettned: thank you, your code works great. AB was just an example, it could be more of them like AB CD..., but what i wanted is your code, thanks once more

Comment: when i have a string `AB 134 aBd " ... ";` how would i change your code to to it? something like `"(AB) ([0-9]) ([A-Za-z0-9]) (\"(?:(?!\";).)*\");"`

Comment: @UniLe close, except for the fact that you need to repeat the character classes (otherwise they will just match a single character of the allowed ones): `@"(AB) ([0-9]+) ([A-Za-z0-9]+) (\"(?:(?!\";).)*\");"`. Of course you can make all of the optional, so it still works with your initial examples: ``@"(AB)\s*([0-9]*)\s*([A-Za-z0-9]*)\s*(\"(?:(?!\";).)*\");"`

Comment: thanks, forgot `+` to add. regex is not so difficult like i thought :)

Comment: `([A-Za-z0-9]+)` is for char and digit, what about `ab_Cd9` it won't be matched

Comment: @UniLe Well, then add the underscore: `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. This character can be shortened to `\w` though.

Comment: thanks, is there any way to match all character instead of `[A-Za-z0-9_]`? i mean that it could be anything there `?\=...`

Comment: @UniLe `\S` will match any non-whitespace character. You should really [check out a tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

Comment: so i tired `(\S+)` but it said unrecognized escape sequenz

Comment: do you use a verbatim string? (with the `@` before the string) if that doesn't do it, please ask a new question. these comments are not meant for lengthy discussions.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think that `AND` operator exists or is even required. [read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator)

However to complete your string finding solution, this regex guide can help you a lot.
Hope it helps.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this `Regex`:

```
AB\s+\"((?:.+\s*)+?(?=\";))\";
```

explain:

> ***`(?= subexpression)`***
> Zero-width positive lookahead assertion.
>
> ***`(?: subexpression)`***
> Defines a noncapturing group.
>
> ***`.`***
> Wildcard: Matches any single character except `\n`.
>
> ***`\s`***
> Matches any white-space character.

Comment: what does my compiler dont' recognize \s?