# How to find an occurence in string?

Tags: php, regex, string, substring

I would like to know what is the best way to know if my substring is in the string.

So, I can has these kind of value :

```
"abcd.tif"
"abcd_A.tif"
"abcd_B.tif"
"abcd_VP.tif"
```

I would detect if "_A" or "_B" or "_VP" is present in the string.

What's the best way ? Using a combination of substr and strlen ?

or use regex ?

Comment: Ever seen the strpos() function (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) in PHP?

Comment: well, preg_match is moer efficient than strpos function, I guess (strpos will need three if/elseif block). So, I would encourage rather to use regular expression.

Comment: @MarkBaker > Indeed, not seen that, but I prefer to use preg_match

Comment: @Rana I'd bet that three calls to `strpos` is still much faster than a single call to `preg_match`, so it is less *efficient*, but also more *readable*

Comment: @ExplosionPills, didn't know preg_match could be so slow, will look into. However, what about such more 10/20 checkings, which we can do in a single preg_match check instead of 10/20 if/else block? I will like to tell this a better implementation...

Comment: @Rana I have no idea at what point `preg_match` becomes more efficient to use, and it's probably not worth it in this case.  String length matters to.  This is not an exact check with respect to this problem, but it does show just how inefficient regular expressions can be: https://gist.github.com/ajcrites/4732454

Answer (score 6):

Use `strpos`, which will give you the 0-indexed position of the needle in the string.  If it's not in the string, `strpos` returns `false`.  (There is also case-insensitive `stripos`).

However, you can only check one needle at a time.  If you'd like to check for any of the three simultaneously you can either use a loop or write the terser but less efficient way:

```
preg_match('/_A|_B|_VP/', $str)
```

...which will return `true` if *any* of those three strings matches.

Comment: To find what matched, and where it was, you can use a capturing group and the `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` flag.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way (I know of :P) is [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).

```
$s = 'abcd_VP.tif';
if (strpos('_A', $s) !== false) {
     // do your thing
}
```

You can do a simple `||` after this, it won't be as short, but it will be much quicker than regex:

```
$s = 'abcd_VP.tif';
if ((strpos('_A', $s) !== false) || (strpos('_B', $s) !== false) || (strpos('_VP') !== false)) {
     // do your thing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use OR operation like (_A)|(_VP) etc. check this question as a hint: [Regular Expressions: Is there an AND operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator) , to use 'OR' in regular expression.