# Regular expression group matching in .NET

Tags: .net, regex

I have this string:

```
of cabbages and kings and more kings
```

I want to match based on this criteria:

```
- Any instance of "king"
- Any instances of "cab" OR "goat"
- No instances of "bill"
```

This regex works for IsMatch():

```
^(?=.*?(king))(?=.*?(cab|goat))(?=.*?(bill))
```

But it just returns 1 group with a 0 length. Is there a way to have it return matching groups so that we can read the matched text after?

Comment: It doesn't work (unless your spec is wrong), and what matched text? You mean the whole string?

Comment: can you post input and expected output?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator

Comment: The input text is "of cabbages and kings and more kings", and I expect to get back a MatchCollection from Regex.GetMatches that has "king" and "cab" in it.

Comment: "No instances of 'bill'" needs to be a __negative__ lookahead (e.g. `(?!.*?(bill))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your pattern use only lookarounds,it would only **check** for the pattern but would never include the matched pattern **except** *any groups in lookarounds*..

If you want to capture the complete string,use the `Match` method with the given pattern

```
^(?=.*king)(?=.*(?:cab|goat))(?=.*bill).*$
```

This regex would match the complete string in **group 0** if it matches the pattern..

Comment: Instead of matching the entire string, is it possible to return matches (or groups) for each term? Like "king" and "cab"?

Comment: @JonTackabury yes..you have to use `match` method..your regex would work perfectly..i.e it would capture the words in the lookahead since you are using groups in the lookahead..

Comment: This seems to just capture the entire string, not just the parts that match, like "king".

Comment: @JonTackabury Can you provide an example string you are working with? The logic above seems to work fine for me. *edit - Never mind; I just noticed your example above. Even that works fine for me with Some1.Kill.The.DJ's suggestion.