# how to create datatype to get email as input from user in java

Tags: java, email

I want to accept `email id` from the user as an attribute like other attributes like `name`, `id` etc. What is the procedure to create custom data type to accept email id from the users?

Comment: String varaible you can use to store emailid

Comment: I didn't understand your question properly. Do you want to know which datatype to save email ID (or) how to validate email address entered by user?

Comment: Do yoou just want to create an instance variable to store the data, or something different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Store e-mail in `String`.
2. Validate it using `regex`.

Ref :

http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html

http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-email-address-with-regular-expression/

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16524798/3603806