# Better Way to Write Regular Expression

Tags: regex

So, I've been trying to write out a regular expression for something like a resistance value, which contains a certain amount of digits and at most one letter, but is always a certain amount of characters total (let's use the example of a four-character resistance code).

First I could do `'\d*[RKM]\d*'` but that would allow something like `'R'`.

Also, I could do something like `'[\dRKM]{4}'`, but this will allow things like `'RRR4'` which is not a value that I would want.

`'\d{1,4}[Rr]\d{0,3} | ([RKM]\d{3}) | (\d{4})'`, though more specific, would still allow `'1234R567'` which is not four characters.

So basically, is there a more compact way of writing `'[RKM]\d\d\d | \d[RKM]\d\d | \d\d[RKM]\d | \d\d\d[RKM] | \d\d\d\d'`?

Comment: I'm not sure if you would like doing it, but maybe the best way of checking length would be using the surrounding programming language. Our company has a list of "validation types" in an XML file, and as well as a regex on each, it lets you set a min/max length. (In this case, just set both to 4)

Comment: `^[RKM]\d{3}|\d[RKM]\d{2}|\d{2}[RKM]\d|\d{3}[RKM]|\d{4}$` is too complex? Or, if you're looking within other text: `\b(?:[RKM]\d{3}|\d[RKM]\d{2}|\d{2}[RKM]\d|\d{3}[RKM]|\d{4})\b`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depending on your regex flavor, you can use a lookahead:

```
^(?!(?:\d*\D){2})[\dRKM]{4}$
```

- `(?!(?:\d*\D)` - Assert that there aren't two non-digit characters.

Or:

```
^(?=.{4}$)\d*(?:[RKM]\d*)?$
```

- `(?=.{4}$)` - Assert that the length of the string is 4.

See also: [Regular Expressions: Is there an AND operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/469913/7586)

Comment: +1 I was cooking up a somewhat uglier version of using lookaheads: `^(?=.*[RKM])(?=(.*\d){3})[\dRKM]{4}$` (or even `^(?=.*[RKM])(?=(.*\d){3}).{4}$`)

Comment: Awesome @Kobi.  Thanks for the link.  If I could I'd give you a +2.

Comment: @jensgram - Thanks. Keep in mind the letter is optional: `1234` should also match.

Comment: @Kobi Uh, didn't notice that. Please ignore my comment above :)

Comment: Your first pattern matches `1234`

Comment: @Casimir - Both patterns match `1234` - Marcus had a `\d\d\d\d` alternation in his pattern.