# Double letter matching using python regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find a way using regex to match words that have *3 unique* sets of double letters. so far i have this:

```
r".*([a-z])\1.*([a-z])\2.*([a-z])\3.*"
```

But that doesn't account for *unique* sets for double letters. Thanks in advance =)

Comment: what is an example of unique set?

Comment: How about checking for uniqueness after applying the regex you've provided?

Comment: What about triple (or ore) letters? Are they allowed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe like this? Seems to work for me.

```
r".*([a-z])\1.*((?=(?!\1))[a-z])\2.*((?=(?!\1))(?=(?!\2))[a-z])\3.*"
```

`(?=expr)` is a [non-consuming regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/469951/999858), and `(?!expr)` is regex NOT operator.

Comment: @Tigran Wont it be enough to compare it against `\1` the last time? Since, we made sure that `\1` and `\2` are different.

Comment: @thefourtheye, in that case \3 can be equal to \2, and that is unacceptable.

Comment: @TigranSaluev Sorry. My bad. Didnt think through it completely. Thanks for clarifying :)

Answer (score 0):

(?=expr) is a non-consuming regular expression
however
(?!expr) is also a non-consumer expression.  This time a not equals in place of an equals.

So enclosing the 'not' in the 'equals' adds nothing. It works without that as well.  However stacking non-consuming expressions does not always work, and a single non-consuming will do the job anyway by using an 'or'  ('|' character).

so

r".*([a-z])\1.*(?!\1)([a-z])\2.*(?!\1|\2)([a-z])\3.*"

Tidied some braces also.  I think this is cleaner and will be more reliable between versions.