# regex for matching three specific character

Tags: php, regex

while attempting a question in SO,i tried to write the regular expression which matches three characters that should be in the string.

i am following the answer [Regular Expressions: Is there an AND operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator)

```
<?php

$words = "systematic,gear,synthesis,mysterious";
$words=explode(",",$words);

$your_array = preg_grep("/^(^s|^m|^e)/", $words);

print_r($your_array);

?>
```

the output should be **systematic** and **mysterious**.but i am getting synthesis also.

**Why** is it so?what i am doing wrong?

** i dont want a new solution :)
[SEE HERE](http://3v4l.org/13IpP)

Comment: I guess you're getting `synthesis` mainly because it starts with an `s` ?

Comment: but the regex will match all the characters not just s

Comment: That's not true, the regex will match if the word starts with either `s`, `m` or `e`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$wordlist = 'systematic,gear,synthesis,mysterious';
$words = explode(',', $wordlist);

foreach($words as $word) {
    if (preg_match('~(?=[^s]*s)(?=[^m]*m)(?=[^e]*e)~', $word))
        echo '<br/>' . $word;
}
//or
$res = preg_grep('~(?=[^s]*s)(?=[^m]*m)(?=[^e]*e)~', $words);
print_r($res);
```

To test the presence of a character in the string, I use `(?=[^s]*s)`.
`[^s]*s` means *all that is not a "s" zero or more times, and a "s"*.
 `(?=..)` is a lookahead assertion and means "followed by". It is only a check, a lookahead give no characters in a match result, but the main interest with this feature is that you can check the same substring several times.

What is wrong with your pattern?

`/^(^s|^m|^e)/` will give you only words that begins with "s" or "m" or "e"  because `^` is an anchor and means : "start of the string". In other words, your pattern is the same as `/^([sme])/`.

Comment: The question is *why* rather than *how* :)

Comment: casimir : i am usin two ^ and thats acting as NOT

Comment: @RishabhRaj: `^` is only used as a negation inside a character class.