# Identify a string by searching for 2 or more RE's in python

Tags: python, regex

Is there a way that I could search for 2 or more words in a string using regular expressions in Python.

for example, if I have a list of strings like this:

```
[red_house, red_door, red_seat, green_door, green_house, green_table]
```

... and I wanted to return red_house specifically, I could do:

```
red_house = [obj for obj in list if re.search("red", obj) and re.search("house", obj)]
```

but is it possible to combine these 2 re.search's into 1?

Cheers,

Comment: you want to get `house_red`,`redredhouse`,`houseredred` too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
re.search("red.*house",my_String)
```

if you know it will be ordered that way ...

if you just know it will have the words, but it may be "house_red" or something instead of "red_house", this might work

```
 if set(re.findall("[a-zA-z]+",my_string)).intersection(["red","house"]) == set(["house","red"]) :
     #do something
```

since sets are unordered you are just looking for intersection with all the words

Comment: what does the .* mean in this expression?

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this (if only two words in any order have to be matched):

```
l = "red_house red_door red_seat green_door green_house green_table house-red".split()
filter(lambda s: re.search('(red.*house)|(house.*red)', s), l)
```

> Out[7]: ['red_house']

Answer (score 0):

You could use look-aheads to get a more general AND operator ([Regular Expressions: Is there an AND operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator)).

But using two separate searches and the python `and` to combine them is clearer and simpler.