# Regex to with a starting letter AND it contains a word

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var str = "I dont have any one";
var str1 = "We dont have any one";
var str2 = "I dont have any more";
var str2 = "I dont have any two";
```

for these string need to find a reg like it should match string **starts with "I" AND contains "one" or "two".**

```
var regx = "/^I/";        //this starts with I
var regx = "/(one|two)/";  //this match one or two
```

But how to combain both with an AND ?

So `str1.test(regx)` should be false.

Comment: Do "one" and "two" need to be *words*, or just present?

Comment: @Sarath did you want to match the lines which starts with `Icecream`?

Comment: @avinash yes and  one and two need to be words

Comment: Should it match `It is one` and `I am everyone`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just match any character between `I` and `one`

```
var str = "I dont have any one";
var str1 = "We dont have any one";
var str2 = "I dont have any more";
var str3 = "I dont have any two";

var regx = /^I.*(one|two)/

console.log(regx.test(str)) // True
console.log(regx.test(str1)) // False
console.log(regx.test(str2)) // False
console.log(regx.test(str3)) // True
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/399wnLks/1/) a fiddle to test

Comment: Nice, all I was searching for this ".*" its misleading in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator

Comment: The title of the question talks about "one" and "two" as *words*, so you might want to throw that option in ("I have none" would match the above).

Comment: And it returns true for `It is one` not sure if OP is fine with this.

Comment: @anubhava Sure, maybe I should add spaces characters around `I` and `(one|two)`

Comment: You do not need to add spaces. using word boundaries should suffice: `/^I\b.*\b(one|two)\b/`

Comment: no Casimer. OP wants to match the lines which starts with `I` that's all. So no need for word boundary after `I`. And also `\b(one|two)` will also match `one` in `:one`

Answer (score 2):

different approach ...

```
var regx1 = /^I/;        //this starts with I
var regx2 = /(one|two)/;  //this match one or two

// starts with "I" AND contains "one" or "two".
var match = regx1.test(str1) && regx2.test(str1)
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you add a word boundary.

```
var regx = /^I.*? (?:one|two)( |\b).*$/;
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/eF8fY4/10)

Comment: *contains "one" or "two"* **not** *ends with "one" or "two"*.

Comment: What's with the boundary after `I`?

Comment: without `\b` after I it matches the line which starts with Ice