# Java regex count size with Pattern

Tags: java, regex

I want check a string with this Patern:

```
Pattern.compile("^0*(([a-q]{6,}|[A-Q]{6,}){6,24})(1{6,})(([a-q]{6,}|[A-Q]{6,}){6,24})(1*0*$)");
```

The length of  `[a-q]` can not be more than 6. And the length of `[a-qA-Q]` can not be more than 24.

For example:  `max 24(min 6(aaaaaa)AAAAAAAbbbbbbbbb)111111...`

But the code use the group (aaaaaa) like 1 element, and should count like 6 elements. And i need use OR to `[a-q]|[A-Q].`

How can i do this with 1 pattern?

Comment: I think you're looking for something similar to this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator

Comment: post some ex for positive and negative matches.

Comment: Not really, i need check the string aaaaaaaaAAAAAAA have lowercase or uppercase in a group at least 6 size and all the string is less than 24 size. Can you help with a example?

Answer (score 0):

not sure if I understood your question correctly but try this pattern

```
^(?=.*([a-qA-Q])\1{5,})[a-qA-Q]{6,24}$
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/28)

Comment: No but thanks, i want know a small pattern first, and then a big pattern with all the smalls, for example, aaaaaa or AAAAAA is my small pattern, (i need the same character repeat in lower or upperCase at least 6 times) And then i need a that this pattern are smaller than 24 characters include.     x  ([a-q]{6,}|[A-q]{6,})*    and this repeat x times... and all characters insite this expression have to are less than 24Sorry is dificult to me explain this.