# How to search two strings in one string?

Tags: php, string

Hi I have to search two strings in one string.
For example

```
$string = "The quick brown fox jumped over a lazy cat";
if($string contains both brown and lazy){
  then execute my code
}
```

I have tried pregmatch like this,

```
if(preg_match("/(brown|lazy)/i", $string)){
    execute my code
}
```

But it enters if loop if one of them is present in the string. But i want it enter the if condition only if both of the strings are present in the parent string. How can I achieve this.

NoTE: I don't want loop over the string. (just like `explode` the string and `foreach` over the exploded array and search using `strpos`)

Comment: `$string contains both brown and lazy` Keyword here is: `and`.

Comment: `$regex = "/(brown)[^.]*(lazy)/i";` much shorter.

Comment: If you were looking for a way to do it within the regex, this post explains how to get an 'and' effect with a regex lookahead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try like

```
if(preg_match("/(brown)/i", $string) && preg_match("/(lazy)/i", $string)){
    execute my code
}
```

Yon can also try with `strpos` like

```
if(strpos($string, 'brown') >= 0 && strpos($string, 'lazy') >= 0){
    execute my code
}
```

Comment: Both your strpos examples were wrong: it will never return TRUE and `>0` would fail if the position is 0 (the beginning of the string).

Comment: @Shomz yes I also came to know that.Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: No, it won't, it should work with zero as well. `>= 0` if you don't like `!== FALSE` that much.

Comment: OMG!!..How could I forgot this simple logic to use an AND Operator. Thanks @Gautam3164. Its simply rocks. I chose the first one.

Answer (score 3):

Late answer, in case you wish to test for an exact match on both words:

```
$regex= "/\b(brown)\b[^.]*\b(lazy)\b/i";

$string = "The quick brown fox jumped over a lazy cat";

if(preg_match($regex, $string))

{
    echo 'True';
} else {
    echo 'False';
}
```

---

- Or, replace it with `$regex = "/(brown)[^.]*(lazy)/i";` if you don't want to test for an exact match, which is a much shorter method.

Comment: Thanks @Fred -ii- for your concern:)

Comment: @BlankHead You're welcome. I was testing at the time and was away from this page while doing that, which explains my late answer. If that's your +1, thanks :)

Comment: Hey. No mention please. :)