# Java pattern contain all strings in the array

Tags: java, regex

I want to check one long string contain multiple string.

I am trying to use below command.

```
          String[] words = {"GAGGAG", "AGGAC"};
          Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("GAGGAG|AGGAC");
          if(pattern.matcher("GAGGAGGTC").find()){
                 System.out.println("find");
          }else{
                 System.out.println("Not find");
          }
```

Results supposed to be Not Find 
because "GAGGAGGTC" contain "GAGGAG" but does not contain "AGGAC"

How can I give option from "or" to "And"

And There is one more option.

```
          String[] words = {"GAGGAG", "AGGAC"};
          Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("GAGGAG|AGGAC");
          if(pattern.matcher("GAGGAGGAC").find()){
                 System.out.println("find");
          }else{
                 System.out.println("Not find");
          }
```

This is also should show "Not find".
Because There is not allowing overlap part.
"GAGGAG" and "AGGAC" is overlapping "AG" part from "GAGGAGGAAC"

Comment: Do you have to use regular expressions? Using `contains` is much simpler.

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a regex for that purpose.

Use `String#contains`:

```
public boolean checkContainsAll(String sentence, String[] words) {
    for(String word : words) {
        if(!sentence.contains(word)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

In your example:

```
String[] words = {"GAGGAG", "AGGAC"};
String sentence = "GAGGAGGTC";
if(checkContainsAll(sentence, words)) {
    System.out.println("The sentence " + sentence + " contains all words");
} else {
    System.out.println("The sentence " + sentence +" does not contain all words.");
}
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/llyKtK)

---

UPDATE

To check that there is no overlapping, the simplest solution in my example would be to remove the words if they are found in the given sentence, so that they will not be present for next checks:

```
public boolean checkContainsAll(String sentence, String[] words) {
    for(String word : words) {
        if(!sentence.contains(word)) {
            return false;
        }
        sentence = sentence.replace(word, "");
    }
    return true;
}
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/VK6tSv)

Comment: I am really sorry it's great but I forgot to mention since begging that does not allow overlapping part.

Comment: I mean sentence "GAGGAGGTC" not allow because there is overlapping part. but "GAGGAGNNNAGGAC" allow because it's not overlapping

Answer (score 2):

You must need to use a `alternation` operator `|` like below.

```
Pattern.compile("GAGGAG.*AGGAC|AGGAC.*GAGGAG");
```

**Explanation:**

- `GAGGAG.*AGGAC` Matches the `GAGGAG` plus `.*` any character would present in-between and must have a `AGGAC` substring.
- `|` OR operator, so that it would match any order.
- `AGGAC` matches  AGGAC , `.*` zero or more characters plus `GAGGAG` string.

**Example 1:**

```
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("GAGGAG.*AGGAC|AGGAC.*GAGGAG");
  if(pattern.matcher("GAGGAGGAC").find()){
         System.out.println("find");
  }else{
         System.out.println("Not find");
  }   // Output: Not find
```

Example 2:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("GAGGAG.*AGGAC|AGGAC.*GAGGAG");
  if(pattern.matcher("GAGGAGAGGAC").find()){
         System.out.println("find");
  }else{
         System.out.println("Not find");
  }   
}    // Output: find
```

Example 3:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("GAGGAG.*AGGAC|AGGAC.*GAGGAG");
  if(pattern.matcher("AGGACFOOGAGGAG").find()){
         System.out.println("find");
  }else{
         System.out.println("Not find");
  }  // Output: find
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your regex to this for a "and" operator

```
(?=GAGGAG)(?=AGGAC)
```