# Delete lines that contain two strings

Tags: file, sed

I am trying to delete some lines in a text file using `sed`. I only want to delete lines that contains two strings. The command `\|` is equivalent to the boolean `OR`. What is the command for the boolean operator `AND`?

I am looking for something like this:

```
sed '/strA'AND'strB/d' file.txt
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular Expressions: Is there an AND operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator)

Comment: @tripleee not a duplicate, sed use a sub part of RegEx implementation

Comment: @NeronLeVelu The marked duplicate is general enough to provide solutions for most regex dialects, though conspicuously not specifically for `sed`.  If you can find a better duplicate, please link to it -- this is a frequent enough question that I'm sure you can find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/strA/!b;/strB/d' file
```

If the line does not contain `strA` bail out. If it does and it also contains `strB` delete it.

Answer (score 3):

```
sed '/strA/{
        /strB/ d
        }' YourFile
```

- AND is a sub filter ( if filter strA, then filter on strB on same content)
- order is no important itself for the filtering but could change the performance depending occurence of each pattern)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the same `\|` OR (*alternation*) operator. The below sed command would delete all the lines which has both `strA` and `strB` , irrespective of the order.

```
sed '/strA.*strB\|strB.*strA/d' file.txt
```

If you want to delete the lines in which `strA` always comes before `strB` then you could use this.

```
sed '/strA.*strB/d' file.txt
```

Comment: This becomes quite heavy when you want the AND of a lot of strings.

Comment: Also, `/abc.*cba/` doesn't match `abcba` even though it should (maybe not in the case of the asker).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put two selectors on one command, but you can put a command between braces and do that:

```
sed '/strA/{/strB/d}' file.txt
```

The bad part in that is, if you have a lot of string you want to test, you may have a lot of `{}` to handle. Also, it is probably not very efficient.