# Intersection of Two Regex Classes

Tags: python, regex

How can create a regex class that is the intersection of two other regex classes? For example, how can I search for consonants with the `[a-z]` and `[^aeiou]` without explicitly constructing a regex class containing all the consonants like so:

```
[bcdfghjlkmnpqrstvwxyz] # explicit consonant regex class
```

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As an alternative to Python's `re` module, you can do this explicitly with the [`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) library, which supports set operations for character classes:

> The operators, in order of increasing precedence, are:
>
> `||` for union (`“x||y”` means “x or y”)
>
> `~~` (double tilde) for symmetric difference (`“x~~y”` means “x or y, but not > both”)
>
> `&&` for intersection (`“x&&y”` means “x and y”)
>
> `--` (double dash) for difference (`“x––y”` means “x but not y”)

So to match only consonants, your regular expression could be:

```
>>> regex.findall('[[a-z]&&[^aeiou]]+', 'abcde', regex.VERSION1)
['bcd']
```

Or equivalently using set difference:

```
>>> regex.findall('[[a-z]--[aeiou]]+', 'abcde', regex.VERSION1)
['bcd']
```

Answer (score 10):

This regex should do the trick : `(?=[^aeiou])(?=[a-z])`.

The first group `(?=...)` asserts that the pattern `[^aeiou]` can be matched, then restarts the matching at the beginning and moves on to the second pattern (which works the same way), it's like a [logical `AND`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator), and the whole regex will only match if all of these two expressions match.

Comment: You may change to (?=[^aeiou])[a-z] in order to also capture the match

Comment: Davidrac, please post an answer so that I can reward you.

Answer (score 0):

The character class difference or intersection is not available in the re module, so what you can do?

using ranges:

```
[bcdfghj-np-tv-z]
```

using the `\w` character class:

```
[^\W0-9_aeiouAEIOU]
```

a lookahead *(not very efficient since you need to make a test for each character)*:

```
(?:(?![eiou])[b-z])
```

using the new regex module that has the difference feature:

```
[[b-z]--[eiou]]
```

Comment: What is the regex module? Is it in Python 3 standard library or is it an external package?

Comment: @MalikBrahimi: no you need to add it manually: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex

Comment: Will it eventually become part of the standard library?

Comment: @MalikBrahimi: probably