# "AND" in Javascript regex... what am I missing?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am working on a regex which would return true if matched words are present in any order.

This approach (discussed here: [Regular Expressions: Is there an AND operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator))

```
(?=.*tag1)(?=.*tag2)
```

matches both `tag1 tag2` and `tag2 tag1` (http://rubular.com/r/374706hkft), in Ruby, but *does not work* in JavaScript. Any ideas?

Edit: by "Does not work in JS" I meant that

```
"tag1 tag2".match(/(?=.*tag1)(?=.*tag2)/)
```

returns `[""]`.

The answer to this question pointed out that the regex works in the format of

```
/(?=.*tag1)(?=.*tag2)/.test("tag1 tag2")
```

Comment: I have a hard time seeing how that would work in any regex engine

Comment: But if `match` does return an array (instead of `null`), it *did* match! Notice that your regular expression matches the empty string (when followed by `tag1` and when followed by `tag2`), which is indeed a part of your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That regular expression works fine in JavaScript:

```js
function check(s) {
    var found = /(?=.*tag1)(?=.*tag2)/.test(s);
    document.write(found + '<br>');
}

check('xxtag1xxxtag2xxxx'); // both found: true
check('xxtag2xxxtag1xxxx'); // both found: true
check('xxtag2xxxtag0xxxx'); // only one found: false
```

Comment: `/(?=.*tag1)(?=.*tag2)/.test('tag1 tag2')` works, but `"tag1 tag2".match(/(?=.*tag1)(?=.*tag2)/)` returns `[""]`. Can you tell me why one format would return a different result than the other?

Comment: @aaandre: test returns a boolean, not the match result. They're different methods!

Comment: @aaandre: The pattern matches a zero-length string when the string contains `tag1` and `tag2`. The `test` method returns `true` when there is a match, and there is. The `match` method returns the matches, and the zero-length string is the match. If the pattern would have anything more than the look-ahead matches, the match would be more than the zero-length string.