# Regex with max line length and maximum total characters

Tags: regex, line, maxlength

I'd love to have a regex with that will allow the following:

A text for which every line has a maximal length, lets say 10, and the total text had a maximum number of total characters (lets say 30).

For example this would be some **valid** inputs:

1)

```
1234567890
```

2)

```
123456789

1234567890
```

3)

```
12
123456

12456
```

And this would be some **invalid** inputs:

1)

```
12345678901
```

2)

```
1234567890

1234567890
1234567890
```

(note that invalid example 2 exceeds the 30 characters limit due to the newlines)

What I have so far is this Regex: `^([^\r\n]{0,10}(\r?\n|$)){5}$` (Test it [here](http://www.regexr.com/3b1bc))
It almost meets my requirements, except that the maximum input is 5 lines instead of 30 characters. I already put a lot of effort in this regex but now I'm stuck.

What modifications does my Regex need to match 30 characters in total?

Comment: i do like regex but this can be done in a programming language in no time without any hassle.

Comment: @yamm I would love that, but i'm limited to regex atm

Comment: `len(text) <= 30 and len(text.splitlines()) <= 5 and all(len(n) <= 10 for n in text.splitlines())` this would be a python expression, which would be True if your criteria mach and False otherwise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a [look ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in your regex:

```
^(?=[\s\S]{1,30}$)([^\r\n]{0,10}(\r?\n|$)){5}$
```

A perl script:

```
my $re = qr~^(?=[\s\S]{1,30}$)([^\r\n]{0,10}(\r?\n|$)){5}$~;
my @data = (
'12
123456

12456',
'12345678901');
for my $str(@data) {
    say $str, ' : ',($str =~ $re ? 'OK' : 'KO');
}
```

**Output:**

```
12
123456

12456 : OK
12345678901 : KO
```

Comment: This does not match *any* of OP's "valid" examples.

Comment: OK, I've just forgotten the quantifier.

Answer (score 2):

You need something like an and oprator. "rule1 and rule2". According to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator) this is accomplished by using non consuming expressions.

```
(?=^([^\r\n]{0,10}(\r?\n|$)))[\s\S]{1,30}
```

I'm not sure, the syntax is correct. But use it as a starting point.

Comment: You forgot a closing `)`, but unfortunately this doesn't match my valid inputs.

Comment: You'd have to replace `.` with `[\s\S]` unless `/m` was applied, which usually isn't the case.

Comment: @Siguza You're right. I have to use [\s\S] instead of '.'.  moffeltje: Even that you pointed me to the missing ) I did not find it for a while. I Edited the answer.  I also removed the second (?= .. , because we want to consume the text now.