# Detect alpha + digit + dash : must contain numeric

Tags: regex, r

I want to logically, find IDs in a file.  These will have only digits, letters, and dashes.  They must containa  digit to be considered.  I could do a Boolean with 2 `grepl` statements but want to do this with a single regex.  I think (SKIP)(FAIL) could work but don't know how.  In the following I want elements 1, 2, 5, 6 to be considered IDs.

```
g <- c(
    "868776767-ddd-dFFF-999999",
    "8888888",
    "bbbbbbfdfdgtfref-dsfcsdbcgwecbgfecshdcs-cdhscgbfsd",
    "bigbird",
    "2",
    "3-4",
    "swe%h"
)

## This works (I want this result with one regex)
grepl("[A-Za-z0-9-]+", g) & grepl("[0-9]+", g)

## I suspect using this could work with a single regex call.
grepl("(*SKIP)(*FAIL)", g)
```

Comment: Check this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to search complicated things:

```
grepl("^[a-fA-F-]*[0-9][[:xdigit:]-]*$", g)
```

or

```
grepl("^[a-fA-F-]*+[[:xdigit:]-]+$", g, perl=T)
```

where `[:xdigit:]` is the POSIX character class that contains `[a-fA-F0-9]`.
The second version uses a possessive quantifier to ensure that the next character is a digit.

If you want to ensure that there is no leading, trailing or consecutive hyphens:

```
grepl("^(?:[a-fA-F]+(?:-[a-fA-F]+)*)?[0-9][[:xdigit:]]*(?:-[[:xdigit:]]+)*$", g)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
^(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z0-9-]*$
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` : start of the string
- `(?=.*\d)` : look ahead for atleast one digit
- `[a-zA-Z0-9-]+` : match more than one alpha or digit or `-`
- `$` : end of the string

**Output:**

```
grepl("^(?=.*\\d)[a-zA-Z0-9-]*$", g, perl=TRUE)
## [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: @TylerRinker no problem.. i think now it will help people working with r too :)

Comment: Why add the wildcard in the lookaround? `(?=.*\\d)`

Comment: @PierreLafortune because the string could have only one digit and that too at the end..

Comment: Yes but according to the conditions one digit is okay. I meant specifically `.*`.

Comment: @PierreLafortune yes.. and how would you ensure atleast one digit?

Comment: `grepl("^(?=\\d)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$", g, perl=TRUE)`

Comment: @PierreLafortune that regex will check for a digit at the beginning only.. try matching `aaa-123` with it and see what happens.. :)

Comment: Should the plus quantifier be. `*` to match just one digit?

Comment: @TylerRinker `*` means zero or more letters and `+` means one or more. Here we have an additional assertion for atleast one digit, so both will give same results always :)