# Regex to match only when expression match is no more than 12 characters long

Tags: javascript, java, regex

I am trying to create a regular expression (Java/JavaScript) that matches the following regex, but only when there are fewer than 13 characters total (and a minimum of 4).

<strike>(COT|MED)[ABCD]?-?[0-9]{1,4}(([JK]+[0-9]*)|(\ DDD)?)</strike>   ← *originally posted*

```
(COT|MED)[ABCD]?-?[0-9]{1,4}(([JK]+[0-9]*)|(\ [A-Z]+)?)
```

These values should (and do) match:

```
MED-123
COTA-1224
MED4
COTB-892K777
MED-33 DDD
MED-234J5678
```

This value matches, but I don't want it to (I want to only match if there are fewer than 12 characters total):

```
COT-1111J11111111111111
```

See <strike>http://regexr.com/3bs7b</strike> http://regexr.com/3bsfv

I have tried grouping my expression and putting `{4,12}` at the end, but that just makes it look for 4 to 12 instances of the whole expression matching.

I feel like I am missing something simple...thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Try `(COT|MED)[ABCD]?-?[0-9]{1,4}(([JK]+[0-9]{1,4})|( DDD)?)\b`. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/qK2gA2/1).

Comment: Also, you may try [`(?!\S{13})(COT|MED)[ABCD]?-?[0-9]{1,4}(([JK]+[0-9]*)|(\ DDD)?)`](https://regex101.com/r/eU2cU4/1). Does either work for you?

Comment: This may be a case where trying to shove too much into the regex isn't worth it. Why not just do the regex, and then if you get a match, take a second step to check the length of the matched sequence (`matcher.group(0).length() < 12` in Java, and similarly in js)?

Comment: @stribizhev your second comment (negative look-ahead) works as desired - just like the accepted answer - you should have made this an answer instead of a comment!

Comment: @yshavit unfortunately, all in one regex was the only option available to me, otherwise, as you suggested, it would certainly be much easier to just check the length of the match

Comment: You really do not need to check for more than 13 characters, 13 is enough. Use `(?!.{13})` instead of `(?!.{13,})`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you are looking for is

```
(?!\S{13})(?:COT|MED)[ABCD]?-?\d{1,4}(?:[JK]+\d*|(?: [A-Z]+)?)
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mO1lR1/1)

Note that it is almost impossible to check the length of a phrase that is not a whole string or that has spaces inside since boundaries are a bit "blurred". Thus, `(?!\S{13})` is a kind of a workaround that just makes sure you do not have a string without whitespace that is 13 characters long or longer.

The regex breakdown:

- `(?!\S{13})` - Check if the substring that follows does not consist of 13 non-whitespace characters
- `(?:COT|MED) - Any of the values in the alternation (`COT`or`MED`)
- `[ABCD]?-?` - Optional `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` and then an optional `-`
- `\d{1,4}` - 1 to 4 digits
- `(?:[JK]+\d*|(?: [A-Z]+)?)` - a group of 2 alternatives:

  - `[JK]+\d*` - `J` or `K`, 1 or more times, and then 0 or more digits
  - `(?: [A-Z]+)?` - optional space and 1 or more Latin uppercase letters

Answer (score 2):

You can use negative look-ahead:

```
(?!.{13,})(COT|MED)[ABCD]?-?[0-9]{1,4}(([JK]+[0-9]*)|(\ DDD)?)
```

Since your expression already make sure that a match starts with COT or MED and there is at least one digit after that, it already guarantees that there are at least 4 characters

Comment: This did it for me - thank you! Here is this regex working with my test strings: http://regexr.com/3bsg2

Answer (score 2):

> I have tried grouping my expression and putting {4,12} at the end, but
> that just makes it look for 4 to 12 instances of the whole expression
> matching.

This looks for 4 to 12 instances of the whole expression because you didn't add a word boundary \b. Your regex works fine, just add a word boundary and your desired outcome would be achieved. Take a look at this [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uN6oQ3/2).

Your regex seems to be very clumsy and looks a little bit hard to read. It is also very limited to certain characters example `JK` except if you want it to be that way. For a more general pattern, you can check this out

```
(COT|MED)[AB]?-?[\dJK]{1,8}(\s+D{1,3})?\b
```

**`(COT|MED):`** matches either `COT` or `MED`

**`[AB]?:`** matches A or B which is optional because of the presence of `?`

**`-?:`** matches `-` which is also optional

**`[\dJK]{1,8}:`** This matches a `number`,or `J` or `K` with a length of at least one character and a maximum of eight characters.

**`(\s+D{1,3})?:`** matches a space or a D at least one time and a maximum of 3 times and this is optional

**`\b:`** with respect to your question this seems to be the most important and it creates a boundary for the words that have already been matched. This means that anything exceeding the matched pattern would not be captured.

See the demo here [DEMO2](https://regex101.com/r/uN6oQ3/3)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, I was about to accept, but it's not quite the solution.

Looking at the last test string of your first demo link, the value has been changed from my initial example. Delete the `\b` at the end of the regex there is a partial match on the line, whereas my test string on that line was a complete match, so the `\b` is reacting to that partial match.

Regarding the regex, yes it difficult to read and very limited, but, unfortunately, that is the case I am dealing with. I simplified a bit and should have written `[A-Z]+` instead of `DDD` - which rules out `D{1,3}`

Comment: Check very well, it is your pattern that is in the link with the exception of `\b'. it matches a part of the last string. Unless you didn't post the pattern very well. For more confirmation, try testing your pattern to test it in another regex engine and it would yield same result

Comment: Test 'COT-1111J11111111111111' against your regex...it matches, but it should not in order to satisfy my question

Comment: i just did it now, but it didn't match. test it with demo2

Comment: ok, demo2 works, but it assumes {1,8} and {1,3} in the regex, which is not true to my situation. thanks

Answer (score 0):

As this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator) suggests, you could solve this this way:

```
(?=(COT|MED)[ABCD]?-?[0-9]{1,4}(([JK]+[0-9]*)|(\ DDD)?))(?={4 , 12})
```

Comment: That works in many server-side regex implementations but I don't think it's supported in Javascript RegExp, which is one of the keywords given.

Comment: @PaulKienitz can't confirm or refute this, since i can't access the javascript docs atm. I'll update as soon as i've got access