# Reg ex - validate password conditions - two out of three

Tags: javascript, regex, passwords

I have the following requirments for password:

1. minimum length of 8 characters.
2. password must contain a number.
3. password must have characters from two of the following groups:

   ```
   uppercase alphabet
   lowercase alphabet
   special characters [!@#$...]
   ```

I used the following regex

```
^(?=.+?[0-9])((?=.*?[a-z])(?=.+?[A-Z]))|((?=.*?[a-z])(?=.+?[~!@#$%^&*()-_=+]))|((?=.+?[A-Z])(?=.+?[~!@#$%^&*()-_=+])).{8,}$
```

playground can be found [[here]](https://regex101.com/r/iY7iH5/19)

appreciate assistance

Comment: How about using 3 separate regexes for the separate rules, then counting how many of those are matched?

Comment: Did you see the similar question (combining regular expressions [AND]) on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator)?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an array of possible character values , using `Array.prototype.filter()` to check input string for at least two of three required groups

```js
var re = ["abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
          , "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
          , "~!@#$%^&*()-_=+"];

var input = document.querySelector("input");

function check(e) {
  var str = this.value;
  var res = str.length >= this.size // check length
            && /[0-9]/.test(str) // check digit
            && re.filter(function(val) {
                 return new RegExp(str.split("").join("|")).test(val)
               }).length >= 2; // check for at least two of three required groups
  // do stuff
  this.className = res ? "valid" : "invalid"
}

input.oninput = input.onfocus = check;

input.focus();
```

```css
input.invalid {
  outline: 2px solid red;
}
input.invalid + label {
  display: block;
}
input.valid {
  outline: 2px solid green;
}
label,
input.valid + label {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" size="8" required="true" id="p" />
<label for="p">Required:
  <br>1. minimum length of 8 characters.
  <br>2. password must contain a number.
  <br>3. password must have characters from two of the following groups:
  <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;a) uppercase alphabet
  <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;b) lowercase alphabet
  <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;c) special characters: ~!@#$%^&*()-_=+</label>
```