# RegExp() logical and and or result unexpected

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a simple filter function in my javascript, based on an input box.

```
function filter(selector, query) {
query   =   $.trim(query); //trim white space
query = query.replace(/ /gi, '|'); //add OR for regex 

$(selector).each(function() {
($(this).text().search(new RegExp(query, "i")) < 0) ? (do something here)
```

So, if I have a table with a list of words, eg.

```
Alpha Centauri,
Beta Carbonate,
Charly Brown,
...
```

and I enter 'alpha cen' into my input box, the function searches for ('alpha' or 'cen') and returns the one record as desired.

However, if I replace the '`|`' with a '`&`' to search for ('alpha' and 'cen') I get no results. Even if I enter 'alpha centauri', I get no result at all.

Why?

Comment: See http://www.ocpsoft.org/tutorials/regular-expressions/and-in-regex/

Comment: There is no & operator in reg exp...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/470602/2055998

Comment: in final what u really want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While a `|` in a regex allows alternation, an `&` carries no special meaning.  Your current code is trying to find a literal match for `alpha&cen`, which clearly doesn't match any of your data.