# Regular expression: And condition not working

Tags: regex

I am using the following regular expression:

```
(?=([0-9]+\s+ok\s+[0-9]+\s+nok)) (?=(ltelidt|eiflmrj5))
```

My expression should find the following pattern:

1. (Condition1): Number followed by `ok`, and then number followed by `nok`. eg: `13 ok 1 nok`
2. (Condition2): It should find either `ltelidt` or `eiflmrj5`
3. The final expression should be something like this: `condition1 and condition2`.

However, my regular expression failed to find any pattern in the following sentence:

```
605sd25                  schklog_1FS     13 ok  1 nok        106m  24_R23F   eiflmrj5  d1us41  fd1d     tm1500  o1t2enb1010                  2m    2016-02-18 23:30:34  2016-02-19 07:14:01
```

Comment: It seems you are dealing with records where fields are separated by tabs (or several spaces). In this case do not use a regex, split the record line by spaces or tabs and check the fields you need with the value you want. The result will be faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using lookaheads incorrectly. Instead, you can get rid of them, and just capture the text between your two groups:

```
([0-9]+\s+ok\s+[0-9]+\s+nok).*?(ltelidt|eiflmrj5)
```

See it matching on [regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/rW9sL6/1).

It looks like a better explanation of lookaheads would be useful. You can think of them as asserting a regex from a given position in the string. So, lets define the positions in the string `abc`:

```
|a|b|c|
1 2 3 4
```

You can see that there are 4 positions in the string. Now, try to apply the lookahead `(?=b)`.

```
|a|b|c|
^
Current position
```

No match, keep going.

```
|a|b|c|
  ^
  Current position
```

Got it, we just matched that from the current position, we get `b`. Now, we evaluate the rest of the original regex, starting from this position.

Comment: I used this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator to learn about the AND condition in Regex. According to the link, my regex looks correct.

Comment: @JohnRambo That's used to match two conditions at the same index into the string. You don't have two things at the **same** index, the strings you are looking for are at different positions in the string.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible for both `(?=([0-9]+\s+ok\s+[0-9]+\s+nok))` and `(?=(ltelidt|eiflmrj5))` to match at the same time.
Perhaps you might want this instead:

```
([0-9]+\s+ok\s+[0-9]+\s+nok).*(ltelidt|eiflmrj5)
```

This says that, there could be any thing between `condition1` and `condition2`.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use positive lookahead `?=`, then you should use the following regular expression:

```
(?=([0-9]+\s+ok\s+[0-9]+\s+nok)).* (?=(ltelidt|eiflmrj5))
```

Consider this regex, `q(?=u)` it matches a `q` that is followed by a `u`, without making the `u` part of the match. The positive lookahead construct is a pair of parentheses, with the opening parenthesis followed by a question mark and an equals sign.

Your regex was not working because your `condition2` was not immediately after `condition1`. There were other characters present between `condition1` and `condition2`. That's why you have to use `.*`

However, I would suggest you to avoid look ahead in your case, as it is not required.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html