# What's a RegEx for "up to three words but no more than 20 characters"?

Tags: regex

I can use `\s?(\w+\s){0,2}\w*)` for "up to three words" and `\w{0,20}` for "no more than twenty characters", but how can I combine these? Trying to merge the two via a lookahead as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/469951/321973) [seems to fail](https://regex101.com/r/xB3nD5/1).

Some examples for clarification:

> The early bird catches the worm.

should match any three words in sequence (including the worm<sup>*</sup>).

> Here we have a supercalifragilisticexpialidocious sentence.

"a supercalifragilisticexpialidocious sentence" is too long a sequence and therefore should not match.

---

<sup>*</sup> In my actual use case I'm going for a paragraph's last three words, i.e. a `(?:\r)` would be at the end of the RegEx and *the* match "catches the worm.") Matches are then applied with a "no linebreaks" character style in Adobe InDesign in order to avoid [orphans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widows_and_orphans).

Comment: Are you using a language here?  This problem would be much more tractable IMO if you were using something like Java.  Regex isn't the answer for everything.

Comment: Well, try [`(?!(?:\s*\w){21})\b\w+(?:\s+\w+){0,2}\b`](https://regex101.com/r/yR0qK1/1), it will require matching at least 1 word

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew 6695 steps, this is not so performatic

Comment: @fdfey: Ok, move the lookahead after `\b`: [`\b(?!(?:\s*\w){21})\w+(?:\s+\w+){0,2}\b`](https://regex101.com/r/yR0qK1/2). The idea is pretty much the same.

Comment: @Tobias : Do you want a maximum of 20 characters for the 3 words combined? Or do you want max 20 chars per word?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The "language" is a GREP-style for Adobe InDesign which is an option to apply a character formatting to anything matching a given RegEx. I definitely agree with your assessment though [:)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/321973)

Comment: @JanDvorak hint: I mentioned that in my question ;) but thanks anyway, that was already one difficult thing to figure out

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Seems good, you should post this as answer so I can accept it

Comment: @LukStorms No more than 20 characters for their combination - I guess up to twenty characters per word would be easier? Something like `(?:\s\w{1,20}){3}` I think

Comment: @TobiasKienzler Wiktor doesn't need the points, but [I do](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1863229/tim-biegeleisen).

Comment: Oh, wait, you wanted the longest substring starting at a given point that satisfies both conditions? I'm afraid I can't help you here. Technically the language is regular, but translating the DFA to regex won't result in anything pretty.

Comment: May I extract a PPCG challenge out of your question? With a bit of luck, an answer will pop up that is also applicable as an answer to your question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen :D The points are a nice to have, but the [point](https://xkcd.com/559/ "pun intended...") is that comments should be used for clarification and (even partial) answers should be possible to accept and separately discussed. Otherwise we end up with many apparently [unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered) questions that turn out to have the answer hidden in a comment

Comment: @JanDvorak Very good point, I always wanted to post one there :) I'll add a link here afterwards.

Comment: Guys, it takes time to write an answer. I am onthe bus and my mobile battety is almost flat. I eill try to copy paste my comment to answrr and will update once I'm at the desktop.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No rush, don't worry :) Thanks for your two versions so far, they look promising. As Jan suggested I'll post a PPCG challenge while we're at it :D

Comment: @JanDvorak Alright, I posted a challenge: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/80179/2775

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match 3 words separated with whitespace(s) at the end of a line or string, you can use

```
\b(?!(?:\s*\w){21})\w+(?:\s+\w+){0,2}(?=$|[\r\n])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wN3sM0/2). Note that in the demo, I use `[^\S\r\n]` instead of the `\s` in the lookahead since  the text contains newlines, use the same trick if you need that.

**Regex explanation**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?!(?:\s*\w){21})` - a lookahead check that fails the match if after the initial word boundary there are 21 word characters optionally preceded with any number of whitespace symbols
- `\w+` - 1 word (consisting of 1 or more word characters)
- `(?:\s+\w+){0,2}` - zero, one or two sequences of 1+ whitespaces followed with 1+ word characters
- `(?=$|[\r\n])` - a positive lookahead that only allows a match to be returned if there is the end-of-string (`$`) or the end of a line (`[\r\n]`).

Now, if your words should only contain letters, use `[a-zA-Z]` or equivalent for your language. If the regex flavor allows, use `\p{L}` Unicode category/property class.

Comment: It took me a bit longer though. Please have a look and let me know if that is OK.

Comment: Thanks, looks good. I started a slightly stricter challenge at https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/80179/2775, please feel free to join in :)

Comment: [`\b(?!([^\w\r\n]*\w){21})\w+(?:[^\w\r\n]+\w+){0,2}(?=[^\w\r\n]*$)`](https://regex101.com/r/xZ3fW0/1) :)

Comment: Put it in parentheses to get groups and you've got an answer scoring 66*2415 = 159390 :)

Comment: I do not know code golf, and no idea what that score means :)

Comment: Code golf is about scoring as low as possible. Usually shortest code, but in this challenge I multiply by the amount of steps in order to punish bad performance.

Comment: Oh :) With the capturing group around the whole pattern version (and with possessive quantifiers): [`\b(?!([^\w\r\n]*+\w){21})(\w++(?:[^\w\r\n]++\w++){0,2}+)(?=[^\w\r\n]*+$)`](https://regex101.com/r/xZ3fW0/2).

Comment: [74x2082 = 154068](https://regex101.com/r/jG5lO2/1) if you make the first group non-capturing

Comment: Sure, it must be non-capturing. You have not specified what regex flavor  it is for. My above suggestion is for PCRE.

Comment: PCRE is fine - I didn't consider there would be too many differences, so I forgot to specify... Please submit it as an answer to [the challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/80179/2775) :)

Comment: I [tweaked](https://regex101.com/r/rM2pL7/2) your suggestion a bit, though I'm not sure it still always works: [`\b(?!.{21})(\w+(?:\W+\w+){0,2})(?=\W*$`)](https://regex101.com/r/rM2pL7/3)

Comment: Yes, because you are checking if the whole substring after the initial word boundary is not longer than 20 symbols (with `(?!.{21})`), not just the number of word characters. That is a simplified version for independent strings.