# Extract elements of a list with more than two characters and matching a pattern

Tags: r, list, apply

I am trying to find the index of a list for which one element matches a specific pattern and has n characters>1, for example:

```
i = "a"
ll = list(c("a"), c("b", "abc"), c("cc", "b"), c("c", "b"), c("ac", "c"), c("a", "bc"))
```

I would like to extract ll[[2]] and ll[[5]]. This kind of gets me to the right path, but not quite because I only want the elements that contain the pattern and have nchar>1...

```
sapply(ll, function(x) sapply(x, function(x) nchar(x)>1 & grep(i, x)))
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Nice, I did not know about Filter! It still considers the ll[[3]] though that I am trying to exclude because it does not have nchar>1 for the element that matches "a"...

Comment: I am trying to get only ll[[2]] and ll[[5]], i.e. "b"   "abc" and "ac" "c", but not "a"  "bc"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `Filter`.  The idea would be to find those elements that have `a`, subset those, check whether those elements have `nchar` greater than 1, wrap it with `any` (if there are more elements in each `list` element) and `Filter` it.

```
Filter(function(x) any(nchar(x[grep(i, x)])>1), ll)
#[[1]]
#[1] "b"   "abc"

#[[2]]
#[1] "ac" "c"
```

Or

```
Filter(function(x) any(nchar(grep(i, x, value = TRUE))>1), ll)
```

Comment: This is very nice solution with base R and had no idea of this function, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
ll[sapply(ll, function(x) any(ifelse(nchar(x) > 1, grepl("a", x), FALSE)))]
```

Comment: Sorry I updated the question with one more case which I am trying to exclude and I get using this... I am trying to exclude the case ll[[3]] where the element "a" does not have nchar > 1.... sorry about the confusion...

Comment: Just change `grep` to `grepl` and you've got it I think.

Comment: @user971102 Updated.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach without using `nchar` would be leveraging the regex more.

> Has n characters>1

Means that there can be some characters and then "a" or "a" and then some characters. As Regex: `"[[:alpha:]]a | a[[:alpha:]]"`. The `|` means "or".
Which leads to:

```
Filter(function(x) any(grepl("[[:alpha:]]a|a[[:alpha:]]", x)), ll)
```

Another, more general option would be use using lookahaeds (~AND) as follows:

```
Filter(function(x) any(grepl("(?=[[:alpha:]]{2,})(?=a)", x, perl=TRUE)), ll)
```

Where `[[:alpha:]]{2,}` means at least 2 Alphabetic characters = `A-Za-z`
and `a` means it needs to have an `a`. See [Regular Expressions: Is there an AND operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator#answer-470602)

**Edit:**

You can always "build" these regex using `paste` or `sprintf` as follows:

```
i="a"
sprintf("(?=[[:alpha:]]{2,})(?=%s)", i) # Second solution
```

In total this looks like

```
Filter(function(x) any(grepl(sprintf("(?=[[:alpha:]]{2,})(?=%s)", i), x, perl=TRUE)), ll)
```

Comment: Nice...but I am not sure how I use it if "a" is variable and i="a" is only one option...

Comment: See my Edit: just use `sprintf` or `paste`

Answer (score 0):

A solution using the tidyverse packages.

```
library(purr)
library(stringr)
library(magrittr)

ll %>% map(function(x) x[any(nchar(x) > 1) & str_detect(x,"a")]) %>%
 Filter(length,.)
```

Comment: Thank you...I get an error though after library(dplyr): Error in function_list[[k]](value) : could not find function "map"

Comment: Thank you Shayaa, I like akrun's solution because it doesn't use other packages but knowing how to do this in other ways is great too, thanks!