# nginx Device Detection Android mobile vs Android tablet

Tags: regex, nginx

detectmobilebrowsers.com provides this line for mobile detection on nginx:

```
if ($http_user_agent ~* "(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile| ...
```

To enable tablet detection, they provide this line:

```
|android|ipad|playbook|silk
```

How can I detect phone or tablet, like at a finer grain? The issue is droid phone has a user agent string like "Android ... Mobile" and tablet just has "Android".

I looked at nginx if statements. There's no and operator, and nested if's lack documentation. I saw the NOT OR regex, and working on a solution using that:

[Regular Expressions: Is there an AND operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator#5730026)

Comment: Could you provide some more details what you actually want to match and what you do not want to match? `android` not followed with `mobile`? That can be done with `android(?!.*mobile)` or something like that with word boundaries.

Comment: That did it, thank you. Feel free to post solution. If not, I'll do it in a couple of days.

Comment: I posted an answer with explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pan to match `android` that is not followed with `mobile` word, you can use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) based regex pattern:

```
android(?!.*mobile)
```

or a version with word boundaries to only check and match whole words:

```
\bandroid\b(?!.*\bmobile\b)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oP9nZ7/1)

The negative lookahead contains a `.*mobile` pattern meaning that if the `android` is followed with any 0+ characters followed with `mobile`, the match should fail.