# Is there an efficient way to test whether a string contains non-overlapping substrings to match the array of regular expressions?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, algorithm

All I want is to test whether a string contains non-overlapping substrings to match the array of regexes in the following way: if a substring matches some item of the array, remove the corresponding regex from the array, and continue. I will need a function `func(arg1, arg2)` that will take two arguments: the first one is the string itself, and the second one is an **array of regular expressions** to test.
I've read some explanations (such as [Regular Expressions: Is there an AND operator?](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator)), but they do not answer this specific question. For example, in Javascript, the following three code snippets will return `true`:

```
/(?=ab)(?=abc)(?=abcd)/gi.test("eabzzzabcde");
/(?=.*ab)(?=.*abc)(?=.*abcd)/gi.test("eabzzzabcde");
/(?=.*?ab)(?=.*?abc)(?=.*?abcd)/gi.test("eabzzzabcde");
```

which is, obviously, not what I want (because `"abc"` and `"abcd"` in `"eabzzzabcde"` are just mixed together in an overlapping way). So, `func("eabzzzabcde", [/ab/gi, /abc/gi, /abcd/gi])` should return `false`.

But, `func("Fhh, fabcw wxabcdy yz... zab.", [/ab/gi, /abc/gi, /abcd/gi])` should return `true` because none of `"ab"`, `"abc"` and `"abcd"` substrings overlap each other. The logic is the following. We have an array of regexes: `[/ab/gi, /abc/gi, /abcd/gi]`, and some **possible** combination of three (where 3 is equal to the length of that array) non-overlapping, separate substrings of the original string:  `fabcw`, `xabcdy` and `zab.` Does `fabcw` match `/abc/gi`? Yes. Okay, we remove `/abc/gi` from the array, and we have `[/ab/gi, /abcd/gi]` for `xabcdy` and `zab.` Does `xabcdy` match `/abcd/gi`? Yes. Okay, we remove `/abcd/gi` from the **current** array, and we have `[/ab/gi]` for `zab.` Does `zab.` match `/ab/gi`? Yes. No more regexes left in the current array, and we always answered "yes", so — return `true`.
**The tricky part here is to find an efficient (such that performance is not too terrible) way to get at least one possible “good” combination of non-overlapping substrings.**

The more complex case is e.g. `func("acdxbaab ababaacb", [/.*?a.*?b.*?c/gi, /.*?c.*?b.*?a/gi])`. Using the logic described above, we can see that if we take two non-overlapping parts of the original string — `"acdxba"` (or `"cdxba"`) and `"abaac"` (or `"abaacb"`, `"babaac"` etc.) — the first one matches `/.*?c.*?b.*?a/gi`, and the second one matches `/.*?a.*?b.*?c/gi`. So, `func("acdxbaab ababaacb", [/.*?a.*?b.*?c/gi, /.*?c.*?b.*?a/gi])` should return `true`.

Is there any efficient way to solve such a problem?

Comment: Well `.test()` just gives you a yes/no answer on whether it matched, but if you use `.exec()` (or `.match()`) you get back details of what matched *and its index* in the string, so you should be able to do something with that to check for overlaps. Regarding your example with `"Fhh, fabcw wxabcdy yz... zab."`, those substrings *do* overlap each other because `/ab/gi` will match three times within that input string.

Comment: One possibility (which is probably not the best, and probably a bit messy): For each regex, make a list of the index and length of every matching substring, then compare the lists for all the regexes to find non-overlapping matches.

Comment: Your test case: `func("Fhh, fabcw wxabcdy yz... zab.", [/ab/gi, /abc/gi, /abcd/gi])`. I would argue that this should return `false`, not `true` (all overlap in 'wxabcdy').

Comment: @nnnnnn @Makyen: "Regarding your example with "Fhh, fabcw wxabcdy yz... zab.", those substrings do overlap each other because /ab/gi will match three times within that input string" / "all overlap in 'wxabcdy'" — it doesn't matter how many times some regex matches or where regexes overlap each other. What matters is that we can extract **three non-overlapping substrings for each match** — e.g. `fabcw`, `xabcdy` and `zab.`: `fabcw` matches `/abc/gi`, `xabcdy` matches `/abcd/gi` and `zab.` matches `/ab/gi`. We see that for each regex, we have separate substring that matches it.

Comment: But` xabcdy` matches all `/abcd/gi`, `/abc/gi` and `/ab/gi`. And, `fabcw` matches both `/abc/gi` and `/ab/gi`. With these three RegExp, it is not possible for there not to be an overlap because the shorter RegExp are subsets of the longer ones (i.e. the shorter ones will always match *all* occurrences of the longer ones).

Comment: @Makyen: "With these three RegExp, it is not possible for there not to be an overlap" — I already mentioned that I don't care about whether regexes overlap or not. I added a thorough clarification of the logic to the question.

Comment: @lyricallywicked, If you don't care about overlap or not, then you need to change the title of your question and additional portions of the text.  Currently it is emphasized that it is about **non-overlapping** matches.

Comment: OK, so you seem to be saying it's fine for one regex to match multiple substrings, and fine for one substring to be matched by multiple regexes, as long as there exists *some* combination of non-overlapping substrings where each *can be* matched by a different regex in the input array. Is that right?

Comment: @nnnnnn: yes, seems right. It's not that easy to explain the problem using only words from natural language, so I included an explanation of the logic in the question...

Comment: 1) sort the target strings by length, start with longest; this is to handle case where one target string is a substring of another, 2) for each target string, find first match, replace matched position with characters known not to match (such as \0's), or alternatively use another bit vector to hold matched positions and skip those positions in future matches, 3) success if you can go through all targets; failure otherwise.  Now step #1 obviously only works if the target strings are actual text strings and not themselves regex's.

Comment: Oops. Not quite. Didn't handle the boundary case where (1) there are multiple choices of a longer target string, (2) the first match is not desirable because, in subsequent matches, a shorter target string matches *partially* this target and partially the letters before or after.  So Step #2 "find first match" actually will need to expand into a full-blown breath-first search, testing each possible position in order.

Comment: This is a very standard search problem which can be solve recursively: `search(string, [head ... tail]) => forall (positions of head in string) search(string - head, tail)`

Comment: @StephenChung: "This is a very standard search problem which can be solve recursively"` — sounds interesting, but I don't understand. Can anyone give an example of how `search(string, [head ... tail]) => forall (positions of head in string) search(string - head, tail)` can be applied to the problem?

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is as simple as -- finding all items in a supplied list in a text string ==> (1) take one item from the list, find all possible positions in the text string matching that item, (2) loop through each possibility, (3) for each one, mark the position as no longer available for future matching, (4) do the exact same thing, but for the list minus the item you already successfully matched, (5) stop when the list has no more items.

Comment: For your implementation, the trick is to maintain the *state* of each "partial-match". As I commented before, you can do this very simply by making new text strings with the matched positions replaced by dummy characters. This, however, creates large memory requires because many new versions of such strings will be created when you go down the recurrsion.

Comment: The good thing about creating new versions of the text string is you can massively-parallel the search. However, since we're talking about JavaScript here, which is single-threaded, that's not an issue.  In a JavaScript implementation, you'd want to keep the text string unchanged, but keep a *stack* of invalid positions as you go down the recursion. When you match the first item of each list at each stage, check through the stack of invalid positions to see if the position is already marked "off limits".

Comment: Using recursive search is very efficient in terms of CPU as well as memory as there are no regex's to compile. You can dramatically reduce the number of positions in the search space by first sorting the substrings list in descending order of length -- meaning that longer spots are invalidated first such that subsequent levels have much fewer open positions to match.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming each pattern should match exactly once, then we can construct a regexp of all of their permutations:

```js
const patterns= ['ab', 'abc', 'abcd'];
const input = "Fhh, fabcw wxabcdy yz... zab.";

// Create a regexp of the form
// (.*?ab.*?abc.*?abcd.*?)
function build(patterns) {
  return `(${['', ...patterns, ''].join('.*?')})`;
}

function match(input, patterns) {
  const regexps = [...permute(patterns)].map(build);

  // Create a regexp of the form
  // /(.*?ab.*?abc.*?abcd.*?)|(.*?ab.*?abcd.*?abc.*?)|.../
  const regexp = new RegExp(regexps.join('|'));

  return regexp.test(input);
}

// Simple permutation generator.
function *permute(a, n = a.length) {
  if (n <= 1) yield a.slice();
  else for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    yield *permute(a, n - 1);
    const j = n % 2 ? 0 : i;
    [a[n-1], a[j]] = [a[j], a[n-1]];
  }
}

console.log(match(input, patterns));
```

This will result in a very long regexp if there are more than a half-dozen or so patterns. To deal with this, we can test each permutation one at a time:

```
function match(input, patterns) {
  return Array.from(permute(patterns))
    .some(perm => input.match(build(perm)));
}
```

If there are ten patterns, we will end up doing a couple million tests.

Disclaimers

- This uses ES6 features. Fall back to equivalent ES5 syntax if you need to.
- The input patterns here are strings. To handle regexps instead would require a little bit of logic to extract the pattern from the regexp, and also escape any special regexp characters appearing in it.

> Is there an **efficient** way to test whether a string contains non-overlapping substrings to match the array of regular expressions?

I doubt that you would call the above solution "efficient", but I don't know if there is a more efficient one. As far as I can see, any approach to this problem is going to involve backtracking. You could match the first nine of ten patterns, and then discover that the last one won't match because one of the earlier nine greedily ate up part of what the tenth needed, even though it could have matched itself somewhere later in the string. Therefore, I will go out on a limb and say that this problem is intrinsically of order `O(n!)`.

Comment: This approach, obviously, does not work if I have relatively many regexes. Too many permutations are required to construct that huge `/(.*?ab.*?abc.*?abcd.*?)|(.*?ab.*?abcd.*?abc.*?)|.../` regex! I tested this in Firefox (for example, for `const patterns= ['ab', 'abc', 'abcd', 'xy', 'xyy', 'xyzz', 'bx', 'baz']` and `const input = "Fhh, fabcw wxabcdy yz... zab, cxy, oxyzzzz Bxyy hhbx HHbbbazzz`, and see `"Error: regexp too big"` message in the console.

Comment: In that case you could run the regexp constructed for each pattern one by one. It might be slow if there were a large number of permutations (for example, taking ten things ten at a time there are three million permutations, but at least you would not blow up on the regexp.

Comment: This will work, but... in practice, I could use it, but only for relatively small arrays of regexes (especially if I have to test a lot of strings at once).