# How do I supply multiple conditions to str_extract in r?

Tags: r, regex

I have a dataframe as follows

```
  1     Tertiary seen.
  2     No tertiary seen.
  3     No anything seen.
  4     Tertiary everywhere.
```

I want to add a column only when Tertiary is seen but not when the regex No.*\. is seen.

```
  1     Tertiary seen.        Tertiary
  2     No tertiary seen.       NA
  3     No anything seen.       NA
  4     Tertiary everywhere.  Tertiary
```

I know I can use `|` in str_extract but & doesn't seem to be accepted as follows

```
Mydata$newcol<-str_extract(Mydata$Text,"[Tt]ertiary&!No.*[Tt]ertiary\\.")
```

Comment: I would go with `Mydata$newcol[grepl("(?!No )Tertiary", Mydata$Text, perl = TRUE)] <- "Tertiary"` (negative look-behind)

Comment: Aha. The negative lookbehind. Thanks. Please post as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a [Negative lookebehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for that, something like

```
Mydata$newcol[grepl("(?!No )Tertiary", Mydata$Text, perl = TRUE)] <- "Tertiary"
```

Answer (score 1):

"AND" pattern can be represented by "NOT (NOT A OR NOT B)" pattern. See also [regex - Regular Expressions: Is there an AND operator? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator).

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

Mydata <- data_frame(
  Text = c("Tertiary seen.",
           "No tertiary seen.",
           "No anything seen.",
           "Tertiary everywhere.")
  )

Mydata %>% 
  mutate(
    newcol = str_extract(Text, "^(^[Tt]ertiary|^No.*[Tt]ertiary\\.)")
  )
# A tibble: 4 × 2
# Text   newcol
# <chr>    <chr>
# 1       Tertiary seen. Tertiary
# 2    No tertiary seen.     <NA>
# 3    No anything seen.     <NA>
# 4 Tertiary everywhere. Tertiary
```