# searching for look-after AND regex combination

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to rewrite my regex for using logical condition AND:

`(?<="pies osa.")|(\w+\s?\d{1,2}) - now it is OR (Pipe)`

I want it to work as find string and check regex.

I've tried: 
`(?=.*"pies osa.")(?=\w+\s?\d{1,2})` - didn't work for me

Text which I'm using:

```
pies osa. Pszczol 10, miod mis kon, pies osa. Kon 15
```

I'm trying to print all words that have been matched. Code need to read out all words after "pies osa." with given regex, which would be only two match: - `Pszczol 10` and `Kon 15`.

Comment: Where is your string that you are trying to match?

Comment: For logical AND: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi I've tried that one from your post, but it didn't helped.

Comment: In a regex question you must include strings that should match and strings that should not match. That makes it easier to answer. Update your question.

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi done, can you help me ?

Comment: You did not add texts and sample output.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I've added text which I am using. Output is empty

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "output is empty"? What is the code you are using the regex with? What does the regex need to match? What are the requirements? If you need to detect if a string contains 2 patterns regardless of their order, maybe you need [`^(?=.*pies osa)(?=.*\w+\s?\d{1,2})`](https://regex101.com/r/gL01Pv/1)?

Comment: I mean that there is no match. I'm trying to print all words that have been matched. Code need to read out all words after "pies osa."  and with given regex. That's all of requirements.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I answered for your comment

Comment: It is clearer now, but still  I am not sure, have a look at [this `(?:pies osa|\G(?!\A)).*?(\w+)` demo](https://regex101.com/r/gL01Pv/2). Although [`(?:pies osa|\G(?!\A))\W*(\w+)`](https://regex101.com/r/gL01Pv/3) looks better.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ok, we're closer to the solution but what I still need from that text is only part after pies osa. which would be only two match: 
- Pszczol 10
- Kon 15

Comment: Sorry, I overdid with the pattern. Look at [`\bpies osa\W*(\w+\s+\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/gL01Pv/5)

Comment: See http://ideone.com/TqPNBj

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Great! It works! 
One more question: How can I concatenate:
 \bpies osa\W*(\w+\s+\d+) && \bosa\W*(\w+\s+\d+) && \bpies\W*(\w+\s+\d+) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
"\\bpies\\s+osa\\W*(\\w+\\s*\\d+)"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gL01Pv/5). The results are in Group 1.

**NOTE**: If the digits may be missing, use `(\\w+(?:\\s*\\d+)?)` instead of `(\\w+\\s*\\d+)`.

**Details**:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `pies\s+osa` - `pies`, 1+ whitespaces, `osa`
- `\W*` - zero or more non-word chars
- `(\w+\s*\d+)` - Group 1 capturing a sequence of:

  - `\w+` - 1+ word chars
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `\d+` - 1+ digits

[Java code](http://ideone.com/TqPNBj):

```
String str = "pies osa. Pszczol 10, miod mis kon, pies osa. Kon 15";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("\\bpies\\s+osa\\W*(\\w+\\s*\\d+)");
Matcher matcher = ptrn.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
// => Pszczol 10, Kon 15
```

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)).