# Regular expression to match multiple set of string patterns using C# in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I currently have a code in C# that counts for the occurrence of a single pattern

```
  MatchCollection collection = Regex.Matches(readedLine, @"work=R");
  countedChars = collection.Count;
```

What to do when I need to find or match a multiple set of string or pattern in a line. For example

if "work=R", "product=X" and "function=V" are all found in one line, then it will have 1 count automatically, otherwise, or if one of them does not match, it will not be counted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular Expressions: Is there an AND operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator)

Comment: It does not answer my question, can I just edit my question?

Answer (score 1):

You want a lookahead, and probably with start and end line markers.

Here's an example:
http://regexr.com/3f8pk

Otherwise, if you don't have to process a LOT of data, you can have three separate regex patterns, and see if your line matches all three.