# Need to create a NOT LIKE Condition1 OR Condition2 Or Condition3 equivalence in Regex

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I'm trying to conduct a NOT LIKE Condition1 OR Condition2 OR Condition3 equivalence in Regex. I want to find all strings which does **not** include any of the substrings `RSBO,RRABO,RSISTA0`

From this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word) I've concluded that one can write `^((?!RSISTA0).)*$` to find all strings which does not include the phrase `RSISTA0`

So for my requirement when I have three conditions that must be met I tried:

```
^((?!RSBO).)*$|^((?!RRABO).)*)$|^((?!RSISTA0).)*$
```

, but then I figured that the `|`  operation should probably be a `AND` equivalence. For this I found that one can mimic the `AND` operation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator)

This gave me the solution:

```
(?=^((?!RSBO).)*$)(?=^((?!RRABO).)*)$(?=^((?!RSISTA0).)*$)
```

This, however, causes me to not return any strings at all, even though I know that there are some strings which does not contain any of the substrings I need to filter out.

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close. You just need to place the words to exclude in the negative lookahead like this:

```
^(?:(?!RSBO|RRABO|RSISTA0).)*$
```

It won't match any word containing `RSBO`, `RRABO` or `RSISTA0` but will match any other text.

[See the demo](https://regex101.com/r/x0tnbm/1)

Comment: Thanks! I've just tested this solution in the program I use, and it works perfectly! I never imagined I would get a working solution this quick. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
^((?!RSBO)(?!RSISTA0)(?!RRABO).)*$
```

I believe this does the trick.  Tested with success at regex101.  Probably inefficient since it looks ahead at every character but I can't find a way around doing it like this.

Edit: I don't think the positive look ahead at the beginning was needed so I removed it from my original answer.