# Replace a string when two strings exist in one regex in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

Given the following input

```
$ cat pre
stuff MACRO1 stuff MACRO2
stuff MACRO2 stuff MACRO1
stuff MACRO2 stuff
```

I want to replace MACRO2 (with MACRO3) if MACRO1 also exists.  Like so:

```
$ perl -ne '/(?=.*MACRO1).*MACRO2/ ? print s/MACRO2/MACRO3/gr : print' pre
stuff MACRO1 stuff MACRO3
stuff MACRO3 stuff MACRO1
stuff MACRO2 stuff
```

(I imagine the `.*MACRO2` part of this expression is unnecessary, now that I think about it)
Edit.  A less stupid version of the above based on feedback so far:

```
$ perl -ne '/MACRO1/ ? print s/MACRO2/MACRO3/gr : print' pre
```

What I am trying to figure out is how to do it with just a regex.  Here is one attempt:

```
$ perl -ne 'print s/(?=.*MACRO1)(?=.*MACRO2)MACRO2/MACRO3/gr' pre
stuff MACRO1 stuff MACRO2
stuff MACRO3 stuff MACRO1
stuff MACRO2 stuff
```

I think I am having some fundamental confusion about how a lookahead operator can be both an "anchor" and "non-consuming" at the same time.  If I think about `?=` as an anchor, it makes sense to me that the above doesn't work.  But that would seem to contradict "non-consuming".

Can anyone define what is meant by non-consuming and show me a regex that would produce the desired results?

Comment: Re "*If I think about ?= as an anchor*", huh???

Comment: Why do you want to do it in just one regex? Breaking the code into easily-digested pieces will make maintaining it easier, faster, and cheaper. If you have trouble figuring it out, then everyone else will too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's get the actual solution out there:

```
perl -pe's/MACRO2/MACRO3/g if /MACRO1/'
```

---

Now, let's look at your peculiar request. As a single substitution, it would look something like the following:

```
perl -pe's/MACRO2(?:(?<=MACRO1.*)|(?=.*MACRO1))/MACRO3/g'
```

Ignoring the fact that this doesn't work because variable-width lookbehinds aren't supported, this is incredibly inefficient. While the time required by the first solution I presented is bound by a factor of the size of the file, the time required by this solution is bound by a factor of the size of the file times a factor of the number of instances of MACRO2!

Comment: My reason for wanting to do it one substitution was mostly just to learn.  If it's a very stupid approach for this problem, that's good enough for me.  I'm still interested in understanding what "non-consuming" means.  Does that part of my question make sense?

Comment: Non-consuming means the body of the lookaround is considered to have matched 0 characters from the perspective of the outside of the lookaround. e.g. `"ab" =~ /a(?=\w)b/` matches, while `"ab" =~ /a\wb/` wouldn't.

Comment: Okay, I think this makes sense.  I think what was throwing me off was the most upvoted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator . It's super-upvoted, so I am probably just misunderstanding that answer.  It certainly doesn't work as I thought it would.

Comment: Compare `'def abc' =~ /^(?=.*abc)(?=.*def)/` and `'def abc' =~ /^.*abc.*def/`. `.*abc` matches 3 character, but `(?=.*abc)` matches zero characters, so `(?=.*def)` starts matching as position 0 too.

Comment: Sigh...no, I still don't get it.  I just do not understand how this operator works and no reading I do seems to clear it up.  I do not get why `/(?=a)(?=b)/` doesn't match for `ab` OR `ba`

Comment: Does `/c(?=a)(?=b)/` make is clearer? Remember, all matches are preceded by an implicit `\A(?s:.)*?`. There is no position which is followed by `a` and which is followed by `b`.

Answer (score 0):

Then there's always:

```
$rec =~ s/^(.*)MACRO1(.*)MACRO2(.*)$/\1MACRO1\2MACRO3\3/;
```

O.k., per comment (what if MACRO2 comes first):

```
sub foo {
    my ($x) = @_;
    $x =~ s/2/3/;
    return $x;
}
```

Then:

```
$s3 =~ s/^(.*)((MACRO1(.*)MACRO2)|(MACRO2(.*)MACRO1))(.*)$/$1.($3?foo($3):foo($5))/e;
```

Of course, this requires the function (I called it foo).

Could possibly be done without a function, nesting match/replace in the replacement pattern to do the same thing, but I was getting a lot of syntax grief from Perl (my fault I'm sure).

Comment: This is interesting and I juuuust figured it out.  One problem is that it doesn't work if MACRO2 comes first. Is that fixable?

Comment: Of course, and probably in several ways., but (and hats off to you and ikegami ... it's been a while, this is fun) it requires a function:

Comment: First, hats off and thanks to you (zzxyz) and ikegami. It's been a while, and this is fun.

Comment: O.k., I put in the previous 2 comments, then added the further edit. Apologies for my newbiehood in comment editing. Learning ...